# Biblatex: submitting to the arXiv

Tags: biblatex, arxiv

I am trying to submit a LaTeX file to the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) which uses `biblatex`.  However, it fails whatever I do.

I first get the message

```
biblatex.sty is not found
```

I have tried including (all from TeXLive 2010) `biblatex.sty` but then I get

```
logreq.sty is missing then logreq.def is missing
```

then

```
! Package biblatex Error: Outdated 'etoolbox' package.
```

I then tried adding `etoolbox.sty` and `etoolbox.def` and get

```
! Package biblatex Error: Style 'alphabetic' not found
```

So I added `alphabetic.bbx` then `standard.bbx` then `alphabetic.cbx` and finally I get

```
! Package biblatex Error: Autocite command 'inline' undefined
```

I also tried incorporating the bib into the main LaTeX file as in [biblatex submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal) but it doesn't help.

Has anyone successfully used `biblatex` with the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) and if so, how?

Comment: how are you compiling you *.tex document?

Comment: @lynxoid: please don't use the answer space for questions or comments. I converted your "answer" to a comment on the question.

Comment: A perhaps less time-consuming exercise: find a computer which is running TexLive 2009 (which is the one arXiv uses) and try to compile your document by putting all the biblatex files in its folder. As for your immediate problem, `inline` is defined in `biblatex.def`, which you'll need to include. You'll probably need all of the files in the biblatex root folder, and some more. But I don't have a TexLive 2009 available, so I can't test it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work as described in my edit as getting hold of Texlive 2009 seemed like a pain.

Comment: Good =) Perhaps you should answer your own question, instead of editing the question? That way it will appear as answered. Also, I don't see why you'd want to use the biblatex from TexLive 2009 instead of 2010 (or 2011, for that matter), the 2009 one is quite outdated.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/biblatex-and-the-arXiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of 2024, this is much easier than it used to be;** [@NajibIdrissi’s excellent-at-the-time answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328346/1635) on this question is outdated.  There’s a great [detailed explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429445/1635) on a more recent question, but it’s both very long and itself now slightly out-of-date, so here’s a quick 2024 summary:

- The arXiv now updates its TeXLive regularly, and [documents it clearly](https://info.arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive.html) — it’s currently on TeXLive 2023 — so it has a fairly up-to-date version of biblatex.
- Given this, submission with biblatex should usually work the same way as with plain bibtex: Upload the biblatex-produced `*.bbl` file along with your other source files, and with luck, the arXiv will successfully be able to build your paper based on those.  So far, this has worked for me each time I’ve tried it.
- The arXiv FAQ lists [a couple of likely sources of errors](https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html#biblatex): backend mismatch (Biber vs BibTeX backend; the arXiv supports both, but your `*.bbl` file must be produced with the same backend your `*.tex` specifies), and version mismatch (between your BibTeX/Biber/biblatex and the arXiv’s; a small version difference shouldn’t normally produce incompatibility in the `*.bbl`, but sometimes might).  In the latter case, Overleaf can be very helpful (even if you don’t normally use it), since it lets you easily [pick which TeXLive version to use](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Overleaf_and_TeX_Live#How_do_I_change_a_project%E2%80%99s_TeX_Live_version?) — so you can temporarily upload your files to an Overleaf project, pick whichever TeXLive version the arXiv is currently on, and compile your project with that to get an arXiv-compatible `*.bbl` file.  I’ve used this feature several times to troubleshoot package-version-related issues in other contexts.

Answer (score 11):

arXiv is still running TeXlive 2016. The version that you can find in TeXlive 2019, biblatex 3.12, is incompatible with arXiv's version (biblatex 3.7).

The simplest solution is to install TeXlive 2017 (not TeXlive 2016, because arXiv switched to TeXlive 2016 when it was almost time to switch to TeXlive 2017, so their version of biblatex is the one in TeXlive 2017). You can get it from ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/

Once you do that, run the old pdflatex, then run the old biber, and send arXiv the .bbl file produced.

---

*What is below is outdated but kept for posterity.*

**Update**: As of February 10, 2017, [arXiv has switched to TeX Live 2016](https://arxiv.org/new#feb10_2017). Hallelujah! It should now be possible to use biblatex when uploading to the arXiv (though this deserves a test).

**Update 2**: Having recently uploaded a paper to the arXiv, I can confirm it works without problems.

Starting with TeX Live 2016, no amount of tinkering was enough to get something that arXiv (which is *still* using TeXlive 2011) would accept.

- Uploading all the needed files to arXiv is no longer an option. Indeed, the newest version of biblatex uses some macro from the package xstring that didn't exist in the 2011 version. The package xstring needs a file named xstring.tex. There is no way of telling arXiv that this isn't my main file (innocuously named "article.tex"), and so it tried to compile it. Obviously it didn't work.
- This means that using biber is not an option, as the .bbl files produced by a new version of biber don't work with old version of biblatex. With TeXlive 2015 using the bibtex fallback worked, because bibtex was backwards-compatible enough that the .bbl files it produces worked with TeXlive 2011. This is no longer the case, as the produced .bbl file contains some macros that weren't present in the old TeXlive (I couldn't see all of them but the first that made the build fail was related to the sorting of entries).

My solution? I reinstalled the 5-years-old TeXlive 2011, ran the old version of pdflatex and then bibtex, and gave that .bbl file to arXiv.

Comment: This is just sad.

Comment: I just found out how to make xstring work: Rename xstring.tex into xstring.def and change the first line of xstring.sty to `\input xstring.def`.

Comment: concerning the update off this post (and maybe my post below) I actually uploaded to arXiv a few days ago and that was the first time, my first upload directly works. So it's really a Hallelujah :)

Comment: But since arXiv don't update their TeX distribution continuously, it is quite unlikely that `biblatex`/Biber submissions will work for a long time.

Comment: Just a heads up that with a current version of `biblatex` uploads to the arXiv will create version incompatibility errors again, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864 and links therein for details.

Comment: Well, if you happen to have an even newer TeXlive, it is now broken again. This is the most annoying thing about arXiv that they don't give you an option to run bibtex/biber, like most publishers do, but ask you to provide a bbl in the *exact* right version...

Comment: arXiv updated to TeXLive 2020 in October 2020 https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive - Hooray!

Answer (score 8):

Just uploaded a paper with biblatex, and it works out of the box. Probably due to their switch to texlive 2011 at the end of 2011.

Comment: Small update: you can't submit BBL files created with TexLive 2012; they have to be created with TexLive 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Since last week, biber-style biblatex `.bbl` fiels should work (will try this week), because arXiv updated their system to TeXLive 2016, see https://arxiv.org/new#feb10_2017

Comment: Did you get this to work? Anyhow, I fear the happiness might only last a few months. `biblatex` and Biber are very sensitive when it comes to version mismatches and if arXiv don't update their `biblatex` versions it is quite likely that an update might break things.

Comment: It worked as smooth as possible, I really just uploaded my files and everything worked :)

Comment: That is good to hear. (Just to be sure: You only uploaded your `.tex` and `.bbl` files?) But do keep an eye on the version issue, as soon as CTAN updates `biblatex` you could be out of luck.

Comment: Of course I just uploaded `.tex` and `.bbl`:)

Answer (score 2):

One possible option I've discovered is that .bbl entry formatting doesn't change necessarily even if the version number has changed. This means one option that avoids having to install a different version of biblatex or having to upload your version of biblatex (but is less robust than those options since it depends on entry formatting matching between your and the arxiv versions of biblatex) is the following:

- compile on your device with your version of biblatex
- find a file on arxiv which was submitted using the current arxiv version of biblatex (when this was written [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03486) I just submitted had the right version)
- Download the source files by clicking "other formats" and then "source"
- Replace your .bbl  file preamble with the preamble from there (or try to merge them if you have particular settings your prefer, hopefully you can see which bits of the preamble need changing)

This is perhaps the easiest method if you already managed to submit one version and are looking to just make a couple of changes to the bibliography for a revision, but not best suited to submitting something for the first time.

Answer (score -3):

It should be enough to upload the bbl file, or include it in the main file (and remove the biblatex package from the preambule).

Comment: This is not so trivial with biblatex.  See [BiBLatex submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/2693)

Comment: You are right! Indeed the format of biblatex bbl file is different than the standard one.