# biblatex and biber-- best practice for submitting to arXiv

Tags: bibliographies, biber, arxiv

I know this question is similar in nature to the one posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26990/biblatex-submitting-to-the-arxiv), but I am having issues with my citations when submitting to the arXiv and wanted to know if there is any established best practice to avoid all of this mess in the future (and how best to fix it now).

Currently, I am using doing most of my work on overleaf.  My paper compiles just fine there, but I am getting the following error when submitting to arXiv:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `family_i' undefined in families `blx@opt@namepart'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
```

I have read elsewhere that this can be fixed by compiling locally to get a .bbl file, and then submitting to the arXiv, but this seems to be insufficient.  It is also unclear to me what syntax is needed to copy and paste a .bbl file created by `biber` into a .tex document so that it will compile correctly.

Comment: I would not use `biblatex` in an arXiv submission. See [Biblatex and arxiv, error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864) and the links in my answer there. If your version of `biblatex`/Biber does not coincide with the version that arXiv is running you will sooner or later run into trouble (either warnings or errors, or just faulty output).