# arXiv upload issue: Emergency stop

Tags: biblatex, key-value, arxiv

I see that there are a ton of posts related to this topic but none seem to address the issue I'm having. Apologies if I overlooked the post I should be looking at.

As the title says, I'm uploading a preprint to the arXiv. I am now getting errors about "! Package keyval Error: family_i undefined." and an emergency stop right after I call \printbibliography. My citations are with a .bib file, but I also include the .bbl file so that should be okay. Here is a very pared-down version of my LaTeX source (I can add back more specifics if the operative issue doesn't lie in what is given here (e.g. not all of the packages I'm using are listed here)):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array,geometry,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,graphicx,tikz,tikz-cd,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,listings}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,block=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{result.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=purple,linkcolor=purple}
\usepackage{ZJSstyle}
\begin{document}
hello world \cite{zjs}
\end{document}
```

It looks great locally, and I also tried it out on Overleaf where it looked the same.

I greatly appreciate any thoughts on what the problem is.

Here is (much of) the arXiv output (SE caps me at 30000 characters so I had to cut ~5000, it begins at the first instance of Error):

```
! Package keyval Error: family_i undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.429

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.429

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on result.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'result.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'result.bcf' (1581132335 >= 1581132333)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'result.out' (1581132335 >= 1581132333)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'result.aux' (1581132335 >= 1581132333)
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3036384/ && pdflatex 'result.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./result.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex))
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arytopaths.code.tex))) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arymatrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
aryquotes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.
tex))) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-arxiv/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/easy/easytable.sty
Document Style `easytable' v1.0 <2001/06/13>.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/easy/easy.sty
Document Style `easy' v1.1 <2001/05/31>.
)) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/bigstrut.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/alphabetic.bbx
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/alphabetic.cbx)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/perpage.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./ZJSstyle.sty) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)

Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex) Footnote detection will not work.

No file result.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package biblatex Warning: File 'result.bbl' is wrong format version - expected
2.8.

(./result.bbl) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Class amsart Warning: Abstract should precede \maketitle in AMS document classe
s; reported on input line 59.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd) [1{/texlive/2016/texmf-var/
fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 2 undefined on input line 83
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 2 undefined on input line 83.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 2 undefined on input line 85
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 2 undefined on input line 85.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `unders' on page 2 undefined on input line 95.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `unders' on page 2 undefined on input line 95.

[2]

Package amsfonts Warning: Obsolete command \frak; \mathfrak should be used inst
ead on input line 152.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/ueuf.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 3 undefined on input line 15
4.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 3 undefined on input line 154.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `diff w convergent' on page 3 undefined on input line
170.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `gv lem 1' on page 3 undefined on input line 170.

[3]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 17
7.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 177.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under suff' on page 4 undefined on input line 1
77.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under suff' on page 4 undefined on input line 177.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref) removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 177.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref) removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 177.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 17
9.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 179.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 19
2.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 192.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `monotone' on page 4 undefined on input line 201
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `monotone' on page 4 undefined on input line 201.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `ineq:thm' on page 4 undefined on input line 207.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:thm' on page 4 undefined on input line 207.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 21
0.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 4 undefined on input line 210.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under suff' on page 4 undefined on input line 2
10.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under suff' on page 4 undefined on input line 210.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `python app' on page 4 undefined on input line 2
10.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `python app' on page 4 undefined on input line 210.

[4pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.2.
7}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv

l.211
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equatio
n.3.9}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv

l.211
]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equati
on.3.9}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again>
\relax
l.213 W
rite $\gt=[0,a_1,\dots]$. Suppose $n\ge6$. If $a_n>1$ then $\gt\not...

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under nec' on page 5 undefined on input line 21
6.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under nec' on page 5 undefined on input line 216.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `cor:useful' on page 5 undefined on input line 2
18.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `cor:useful' on page 5 undefined on input line 218.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `rmk' on page 5 undefined on input line 229.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `rmk' on page 5 undefined on input line 229.

[5]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `under suff' on page 6 undefined on input line 2
58.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `under suff' on page 6 undefined on input line 258.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `when ones' on page 6 undefined on input line 25
9.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `when ones' on page 6 undefined on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `abcde bounds' on page 6 undefined on input line
259.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `abcde bounds' on page 6 undefined on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `python app' on page 6 undefined on input line 2
59.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `python app' on page 6 undefined on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `unders' on page 6 undefined on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `unders' on page 6 undefined on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `ineq:thm' on page 6 undefined on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `eye test' on page 6 undefined on input line 261
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eye test' on page 6 undefined on input line 261.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `eye test' on page 6 undefined on input line 261
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eye test' on page 6 undefined on input line 261.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `mathematica app' on page 6 undefined on input l
ine 261.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `mathematica app' on page 6 undefined on input line 26
1.

<a1-75.pdf, id=101, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a1-75.pdf>
<a2-75.pdf, id=102, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a2-75.pdf>
<a3-75.pdf, id=103, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a3-75.pdf>
<a4-75.pdf, id=104, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a4-75.pdf>
<pi-75.pdf, id=105, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use pi-75.pdf>
<a5-75.pdf, id=106, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a5-75.pdf>
<a6-75.pdf, id=107, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a6-75.pdf>
<a7-75.pdf, id=108, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a7-75.pdf>
<a8-75.pdf, id=109, 361.35pt x 360.34625pt> <use a8-75.pdf>

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `no best' on page 6 undefined on input line 276.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `no best' on page 6 undefined on input line 276.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref) removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 276.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `no best' on page 6 undefined on input line 295.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `no best' on page 6 undefined on input line 295.

[6] [7 <./a1-75.pdf> <./a2-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./a2-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
> <./a3-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./a3-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
> <./a4-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./a4-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
> <./pi-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./pi-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
> <./a5-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./a5-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
> <./a6-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./a6-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
> <./a7-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./a7-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
> <./a8-75.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./a8-75.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with
page group included in a single page
>]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `small M' on page 8 undefined on input line 315.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `small M' on page 8 undefined on input line 315.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `code:small M' on page 8 undefined on input line
315.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `code:small M' on page 8 undefined on input line 315.

<fig.pdf, id=134, 578.16pt x 433.62pt> <use fig.pdf>
Underfull \vbox (badness 4353) has occurred while \output is active [8 <./fig.p
df>]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `cycle' on page 9 undefined on input line 372.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `cycle' on page 9 undefined on input line 372.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `cor:useful' on page 9 undefined on input line 3
72.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `cor:useful' on page 9 undefined on input line 372.

[9]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `runs' on page 10 undefined on input line 379.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `runs' on page 10 undefined on input line 379.

<fig2.pdf, id=162, 578.16pt x 433.62pt> <use fig2.pdf> [10 <./fig2.pdf>]

LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `help 3' on page 11 undefined on input line 401.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `help 3' on page 11 undefined on input line 401.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `sigma and tau formulas' on page 11 undefined on
input line 408.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sigma and tau formulas' on page 11 undefined on input
line 408.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `no best' on page 11 undefined on input line 413.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `help 3' on page 11 undefined on input line 413.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `no best' on page 11 undefined on input line 413
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `no best' on page 11 undefined on input line 413.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `help 3' on page 11 undefined on input line 413.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `help 3' on page 11 undefined on input line 413.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `unders' on page 11 undefined on input line 422.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `unders' on page 11 undefined on input line 422.


! Package keyval Error: family_i undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.428

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.428

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on result.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'result.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'result.aux' (1581132336 >= 1581132335)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'result.bcf' (1581132336 >= 1581132335)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'result.out' (1581132336 >= 1581132335)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3036384/ && tex 'result.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./result.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
{amsart}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
{amsart}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on result.log.

[verbose]: tex 'result.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3036384/ && tex 'result.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./result.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
{amsart}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
{amsart}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on result.log.

[verbose]: tex 'result.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'result.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

[Previous problem (resolved): The arXiv autocompiler is crashing when it reaches the line \begin{document} in my document]

Comment: A crash at `\begin{document}` means that the problem is happening either with a package you are loading, or a command defined in your preamble.  The error message in the log does point to the `hyperref` package.  `hyperref` should almost always be loaded *after* other packages; your example shows it being loaded before `biblatex`.  Try moving `hyperref` *after* `biblatex` and see if this helps.

Comment: Thank you -- this resolved the \begin{document} error, and now the error is the "! Package keyval Error: family_i undefined." and now there seems to be an emergency stop immediately after where I do \printbibliography (though it might be numbering lines differently than on my local TeXShop). Do you happen to know what the source of these errors is?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with `biblatex`.  But the new error message does give a clue, and I've added a couple of tags to the question to try to attract people who might know what to do about that.  You might edit the new error message into your question (noting the change you made already) so the necessary information is all in one place.

Comment: Will do, thank you!

Comment: Basically it comes down to the issue that your local installation (and Overleaf) runs a different version of `biblatex` than the arXiv. Have a look at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/biblatex-and-the-arXiv, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26990/35864

Comment: Ah, ok. This explains it, thank you. It seems to work with manual citations (I only have 10 so it's not so onerous to do by hand).