# How to change style in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

How can I use change style in `biblatex`?

I want to use a specific style, probably ACM or IEEE and I don't know how to change that.

Below is the current code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{MyCollection}
\begin{document} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[style=IEEE,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}`

Comment: For ACM have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37006/biblatex-style-matching-stock-acm-style

Comment: oh so that is reverting to 'style' \bibliographystyle{} not using {biblatex}. Thats easy but I need sorting as none too. Do you know how to do sorting as none  in bibliographystyle{} style?

Comment: Got it...\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliographystyle{acm}

Comment: @sab You seem to be mixing 'traditional' BibTeX up with `biblatex`. In the first instance I'd recommend taking a look at the [`biblatex` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex).

Answer (score 14):

As an introduction to biblatex, you might want to read the [biblatex tag info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/biblatex/info) and maybe an [example of basic usage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots).

`biblatex` comes with a variety of styles, 
these are described in the [biblatex documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (section 3.3), 
more styles can be found [on CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/).
There exists a contributed style named IEEE or [biblatex-ieee](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee). 
You can easily use it as shown in the following MWE (or as in the comment by Harish Kumar):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{MyCollection.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \cite{sigfridsson}.
At vero eos et accusam duo dolores \cite{kastenholz}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This MWE uses [`biber`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber) as a backend for sorting and [`\addbibresource{}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-addbibresource-over-bibliography) instead of `\bibliography{}`.

An ACM style does not yet exist, you would have to [define a style yourself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles). Again, Harish Kumar gave a good [starting point for defining an ACM style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37006/biblatex-style-matching-stock-acm-style). In the answer to that question, there are two examples, the first uses bibtex for formatting, the second example uses biblatex. These two [should not be confused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/what-is-the-difference-between-bibtex-and-biblatex).

Comment: Is ACM at all like the IEEE style. I'm always willing to take on styles generally in the area I understand (numeric ones, not too complex, etc.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. @lockstep starts from numeric in the question linked, so I would guess yes. The bibtex style is described here: http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/