# How to include bib file in Tex

Tags: biblatex

I need to submit my TeX file to journal but they request

> Do not include a separate `.bib` file or `.bbl` file with your submission

and

> please run BibTeX before submitting your paper, and include (read-in) the resulting .bbl file within the reference section of your paper

If I upload a TeX file but not the `.pdf` file including the `.bib` results. How should I merge my `.bib` file  with my TeX file ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You might start by checking the folder of your compiled TeX file to find a file with the `.bbl` extension. That is your processed `.bib` file. Then you can include the contents of that file in your bibliography and citations will work. I would really consider issuing a complaint to the journal as this is a ridiculous requirement.

Comment: See [Herbert's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/15925) to essentially the same question.

Comment: @percusse They just want a single document. Just substituting the `\bibliographystyle`-`\bibliography` pair with the contents of the `.bbl` file is what's needed.

Comment: @AndrewSwann That is good if `biblatex` is used. For "old style" bibliography with BibTeX that's meaningless.

Comment: @egreg The question is tagged as `biblatex` so I assume that is what is being used.  The publisher is probably giving instructions based on an author using standard `bibtex` instead.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Oh, I see the point. Now it's kerr's turn to be more precise about this.

Comment: @egreg Yes that's what I meant but I guess *bibliography* word made it confusing. I mean to the point in your TeX file. Sorry about that.

Comment: @percusse -- this may seem a ridiculous requirement, but if you are at all familiar with publishers' journal production systems, you would see why it's requested.  even the most robust automatic systems break down, and "additional" files can be lost.  that would result in delay in publication, with the publisher having to go back to the author to get another copy.  that, in turn, is not advantageous for the author, who is not only inconvenienced, but may him/herself have mislaid the required file, resulting in even more delay.  think insurance.

Comment: this question specifically mentions `bibtex`, so `biblatex` is not an appropriate tag.  note also that some publishers are not able to handle reference lists prepared with `biblatex`, though some other formats may be possible in some cases (e.g. `amsrefs`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can relate to that but that's not the author's concern, not even the slightest bit if you consider how much is charged for a mediocre quality. I have to disappoint you that I couldn't care less. I have to demand some quality after all (note that I think of IEEE constantly while I'm typing. I don't know how it is in the math circles but I can safely say that in engineering domain it's substandard) Besides that a publisher can not loose my files. I can't accept that while everything else is handled automatically. They never loose my extra page charges. Why my bib file?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Also my files are handled automatically so I would really get suspicious if they don't loose my article TeX file but only the bib file. At its best, it's a bad logistics design. I have to conclude that if a publisher is losing files it's their incompetence.

Comment: @percusse -- incompetence it might be, but files are processed here over a network, and a network crash early last friday morning left everything out of the water until about noon today.  at the very least, someone submitting multiple files should bundle them as a zip or tar file, but you'd be surprised how many authors don't know how, or how often not all necessary files are sent.  the math society doesn't have page charges (hasn't for many years); we try to run a tight, efficient ship, but we need the authors' help too.

Answer (score 7):

As long as `bibtex` is used, you should be able to copy the contents of the `.bbl` file directly into the content of your paper in the appropriate spot. If you're using `biblatex`, see [Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/herbert)'s answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/18628 for a workaround.

---

Additionally, if you're using `biblatex`, you should note, as [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) points out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12179/18628), that:

> "[...] you cannot be sure of the package or engine availability on journal systems."

The implication is that while the `biblatex` workaround mentioned by Herbert will work in some cases, it isn't an ideal substitute for `bibtex` in journals with this requirement.

Comment: Thanks all , I did successfully in both bibtex and biblatex

Answer (score 2):

## latexpand

(with TexLive distributed)

You can try

```
$ latexpand --expand-bbl mytexfile.bbl mytexfile.tex
```

Comment: This is a good way to see what actually happened in compiling.