# Biblatex: include bbl, problem with "verb" field

Tags: biblatex

This is a follow up question to [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal).

As noted in the comments to [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/11984), some users have problems with his solution as compiling produces the error `Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition \blx@bblfile@biber ...2004} \verb {eprint} \verb cond-mat/0407066 \endverb`.

I have narrowed the problem down: the issue are `\verb` "fields" in the bbl. If those are present (for example for DOI or URL), then the error above is thrown *unless* the bbl is included via `\input`.

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

%-------------- start insert modified commands ------------------
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile@biber{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup
  \blx@bblstart

\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nty}
    \entry{Agarwal2007}{article}{}
      \verb{doi}
      \verb 10.2139/ssrn.943524  %%--PROBLEM--%%
      \endverb
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection

  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}
\makeatother
%-------------- end insert modified commands --------------

\begin{document}

Some words \cite{Agarwal2007}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Compiling does not work unless commenting `\verb 10.2139/ssrn.943524`.

Edit: the code to generate the bbl is

```
@article{Agarwal2007,
author = {Agarwal, S.},
doi = {10.2139/ssrn.943524},
year = {2006}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problematic part should be in some external file. So use the filecontents-environment to create it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testinput-bbl.bbl}
\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nty}
    \entry{Agarwal2007}{article}{}
      \verb{doi}
      \verb 10.2139/ssrn.943524  
      \endverb
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\end{filecontents}
%-------------- start insert modified commands ------------------
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile@biber{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup
  \blx@bblstart
  \input{testinput-bbl.bbl}%<------------
  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}
\makeatother
%-------------- end insert modified commands --------------

\begin{document}

Some words \cite{Agarwal2007}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### Edit April 2017

Due to changes in biblatex the redefinition of `\blx@bblfile@biber` no longer work as the command doesn't exist anymore. The following is a replacement. It should also work with older biblatex. It also will issue a warning if the content of the bbl doesn't fit the biblatex version.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%Use the starred version of filecontents to avoid comments in the written file
%Insert the complete bbl in the environment including the starting comments!

\begin{filecontents*}{testinput-bbl.bbl}
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.8 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \sortlist[entry]{nty/global/}
    \entry{doody}{article}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=936cee5fdd47aac6238f650db8b23a07}{%
           family={Doody},
           familyi={D\bibinitperiod},
           given={Terrence},
           giveni={T\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{936cee5fdd47aac6238f650db8b23a07}
      \strng{fullhash}{936cee5fdd47aac6238f650db8b23a07}
      \strng{authornamehash}{936cee5fdd47aac6238f650db8b23a07}
      \strng{authorfullhash}{936cee5fdd47aac6238f650db8b23a07}
      \field{sortinit}{D}
      \field{sortinithash}{d10b5413de1f3d197b20897dd0d565bb}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{annotation}{An \texttt{article} entry cited as an excerpt from a \texttt{collection} entry. Note the format of the \texttt{related} and \texttt{relatedstring} fields}
      \field{journaltitle}{The Journal of Narrative Technique}
      \field{langid}{english}
      \field{langidopts}{variant=american}
      \field{number}{3}
      \field{relatedstring}{\autocap{e}xcerpt in}
      \field{title}{Hemingway's Style and {Jake's} Narration}
      \field{volume}{4}
      \field{year}{1974}
      \field{related}{1e63d4bbc14872275675171be2dfa906}
      \field{pages}{212\bibrangedash 225}
      \range{pages}{14}
    \endentry
    \entry{1e63d4bbc14872275675171be2dfa906}{collection}{dataonly}
      \name{editor}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=cf369effe2b1de0066543cc38f7f8369}{%
           family={Matuz},
           familyi={M\bibinitperiod},
           given={Roger},
           giveni={R\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {Detroit}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Gale}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{cf369effe2b1de0066543cc38f7f8369}
      \strng{fullhash}{cf369effe2b1de0066543cc38f7f8369}
      \strng{editornamehash}{cf369effe2b1de0066543cc38f7f8369}
      \strng{editorfullhash}{cf369effe2b1de0066543cc38f7f8369}
      \field{sortinit}{M}
      \field{sortinithash}{c26a05ef03e4429073ed5c825140fac3}
      \field{labelnamesource}{editor}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{clonesourcekey}{matuz:doody}
      \field{annotation}{A \texttt{collection} entry providing the excerpt information for the \texttt{doody} entry. Note the format of the \texttt{pages} field}
      \field{langid}{english}
      \field{langidopts}{variant=american}
      \field{title}{Contemporary Literary Criticism}
      \field{volume}{61}
      \field{year}{1990}
      \field{pages}{204\bibrangedash 208}
      \range{pages}{5}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xpatch}

%Patch the biblatex input command.
%replace "testinput-bbl" if you change the name above.
%disable if you want to run biblatex/biber normally
\makeatletter         
\patchcmd\blx@bblinput{\blx@blxinit}
                      {\blx@blxinit
                       \def\jobname{testinput-bbl}%new jobname
                      }{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} %not needed but doesn't harm either

\begin{document}

Some words \cite{doody}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's already in my question above. But it defeats the purpose of including the bbl in the file, which is what I need.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen that you wrote about input. Well then use filecontents to write everything during the compilation to an external file. \verb needs to do catcode changes.

Comment: Can you include the `filecontents` part into your answer? I will then accept it.

Answer (score 2):

use for the two verb lines::

```
...
  \field{doi}{10.2139/ssrn.943524}
...
```

It worked for me:

[image]

Comment: That prints the verb fields above the bibliography (completely outside the references).

Comment: That has nothing to do with my setting. It is a problem with your generated code. The main problem is `\verb{doi}`. Replace it with `\texttt` and everything and there is no error, but also not a valid bibliography output.

Comment: But I'm not generating the code of the bbl, Biber v1.8 does and creates \verb fields for DOIs and URLs.

Comment: I know that, but then you have to use the definitions of `\verb` and `\endverb`.

Comment: I've added a screenshot above to show the problem of the doi being outside the bibliography when I use the suggested definitions of `\verb` and `\endverb`.

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: Unfortunately that does not really work: (i) it's not automatic, (ii) it does not work with URLs as they require escaping of special characteris.

Comment: The argument is already read verbatim, special characters are possible!