# arXiv says that it is possible to upload the .bbl file, but keep getting errors related to BibLaTeX/Biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, arxiv

I use Biber for my reference in the following format:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
...
\addbibresource{REF.bib}
...
\printbibliography
```

[arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) recommends to [Include .bbl files if you use BibTeX](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#bibtex), but gives the following error when I try and upload my `bbl` file:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \sortlist
{entry}{nyt}
```

I have tried to inline my `bbl` file using the following [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal), excluding the first `\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}` group and the last `\endinput` line, but this gives the error: `! Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match it's definition`.

Using the follow-up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166518/biblatex-include-bbl-problem-with-verb-field), I have been able to get it to compile with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{REF.bib} don't need this now that it is inlined
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testinput-bbl.bbl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%% copy here the contents of the created bbl file
%% (do not include "Missing 'biblatex' package" group -or- final \endinput)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{filecontents}
%-------------- start insert modified commands ------------------
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile@biber{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup
  \blx@bblstart
  \input{testinput-bbl.bbl}%<------------
  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}
\makeatother
%-------------- end insert modified commands --------------
...
\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The problem is that if I upload this to arXiv, it **still** gives me an error, even though it compiles locally. How do I solve this? I thought about the possibility of [incompatible versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26990/biblatex-submitting-to-the-arxiv) of LaTeX, since I'm using distro 2015 and they are using 2011, but I haven't tested this. A detailed description of version incompatibilities can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429445/30158).

Comment: A better answer is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429445/30158

Comment: That's true. When I wrote this post, I hadn't tested the version incompatibilities. Glad someone wrote up a detailed description of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is much easier than inlining the `bbl` file and can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181169/publishing-to-arxiv-using-biblatex-biber). Given the following code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
...
\addbibresource{REF.bib}
...
\printbibliography
```

...delete the current `bbl` file; set the backend driver to bibtex `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}`; and run your standard `latex`, `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex` combo to produce the bbl file. Upload the `bbl` file and the `tex` file to [arXiv.org](http://arXiv.org), with both files in the same folder/directory and with the same base name. Ex: `manuscript.bbl` and `manuscript.tex`.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
...
\addbibresource{REF.bib}
...
\printbibliography
```

The contents of the `bbl` file should look very different, for example starting with an `\entry` section.

```
\entry{aarseth2000-allegories}{inbook}{}
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{}%
     {Aarseth}{A.}%
     {Espen}{E.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
  }
  \list{publisher}{1}{%
    {University of Jyv\"{a}skyl\"{a}}%
  }
  \keyw{anomalies, space, time, digital, MUD, virtual, world, indoor, outdoor}
  \strng{namehash}{AE1}
  \strng{fullhash}{AE1}
  \field{labelyear}{2001}
  \field{sortinit}{A}
  \field{chapter}{Allegories of Space. The Question of Spatiality in Computer
  Games}
  \field{pages}{152\bibrangedash 171}
  \field{title}{Cybertext yearbook 2000}
  \verb{url}
  \verb http://cybertext.hum.jyu.fi/index.php?browsebook=4
  \endverb
  \field{year}{2001}
\endentry
```