# Biblatex for Nature Publishing Group submission: folding everything into a single tex file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, pdftex, journal-publishing

This is a follow up question to [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal) and to [Biblatex: include bbl, problem with "verb" field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166518/biblatex-include-bbl-problem-with-verb-field/362356#362356).

I am using the [biblatex nature style](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature?lang=en), which uses `\verb` a lot, resulting in compilation errors when using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/32840). I tried [Ulrike's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166526/32840), but the code generates no bibliography whatsoever with pdfLaTeX/Biber (TeXLive 2016). It does, beautifully, if references are stored in bib files and included via `\addbibresource{}`. A MWE is appended to illustrate this problem.

I am not sure if the "all tex" failure is caused by some of the biblatex options I use; most of them seem necessary to meet the journal's specifications, but maybe not all. I have >700 references so [@Herbert's manual formatting fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166520/32840) is impractical.

I'd be grateful for any insight on how to make this work. The journal, unfortunately, won't accept any bibtex or biblatex auxiliary files.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,url}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr,lineno}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=nature,date=year,backend=biber,natbib=true,doi=false,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issue}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{isbn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{isbn}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenum}
  {}
  {\printfield{labelnumber}}
  {}
  {}

% define bib resources
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bbl}
\refsection{0}
 \sortlist{entry}{nty}
  \entry{A1}{article}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}{%
       family={{\relax PAGES2k Consortium}},
       familyi={{\relax PAGES2k Consortium}\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
  \list{publisher}{1}{%
    {Nature Publishing Group, a division of Macmillan Publishers Limited. All Rights Reserved.}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \strng{fullhash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \strng{authornamehash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \strng{authorfullhash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \field{sortinit}{5}
  \field{sortinithash}{c9df3c9fb8f555dd9201cedc5e343021}
  \field{labelnamesource}{author}
  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{isbn}{1752-0894}
  \field{journaltitle}{Nature Geoscience}
  \field{month}{05}
  \field{number}{5}
  \field{title}{Continental-scale temperature variability during the past two millennia}
  \field{volume}{6}
  \field{year}{2013}
  \field{pages}{339\bibrangedash 346}
  \range{pages}{8}
  \verb{doi}
  \verb 10.1038/ngeo1797
  \endverb
  \verb{url}
  \verb http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ngeo1797
  \endverb
\endentry 
\entry{A2}{online}{}
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}{%
       family={{\relax PAGES 2k Consortium}},
       familyi={{\relax PAGES 2k Consortium}\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \strng{fullhash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \strng{authornamehash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \strng{authorfullhash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \field{sortinit}{6}
  \field{sortinithash}{02bbed3ed82f61ae046619460488516d}
  \field{labelnamesource}{author}
  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{howpublished}{FigShare}
  \field{title}{A really nice data citation}
  \field{urlyear}{2017}
  \field{urldateera}{ce}
  \verb{doi}
  \verb 10.6084/123.456mwe
  \endverb
  \verb{url}
  \verb https://figshare.com/s/12345678
  \endverb
\endentry 
\endsortlist
\endrefsection
\end{filecontents}

%-------------- start insert modified commands ------------------
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile@biber{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup
  \blx@bblstart
  \input{mybib.bbl}%<------------
  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}
\makeatother
%-------------- end insert modified commands ------------------
\begin{document}
 In this paper, we have regular citations \cite{A1} and data citations \cite{A2}. Both are important.

 % %%%%%%%%%   Citations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\printbibliography[title={References},nottype=online,resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[title={Data citations},type=online,resetnumbers=true]    
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The internal command of biblatex have changed. `\blx@bblfile@biber` no longer exists. You could try the following instead.

1. Use the `filecontents*` environment instead of `filecontents`.
2. Add *everything* from the .bbl -- including the starting comments.
3. Use the following redefinition

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \def\blx@bblinput{%
    \begingroup
    \blx@info@noline{Trying to load bibliographic data..}%
    \blx@blxinit
    \def\jobname{mybib}%  added    
    \blx@bblfile
    \endgroup}
   \makeatother
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike. I'm getting  "LaTeX Error: File `filecontents*.sty' not found." @moewe's solution works great, however.

Comment: I didn't wrote use the `filecontents*` *package*  but the *environment* so change \begin{filecontents}.

Comment: That's what I did, and it produced the aforementioned error.

Comment: No your error message cleary shows that you tried `\usepackage{filecontents*}` . That's wrong the package name is still `filecontents`. Only the environment should change and use a star (to avoid that LaTeX adds a  comment at the begin). And while @moewe's solution work, I prefer mine as it will also do the necessary version checks and warn you if the bbl has not the format needed by the biblatax version.

Comment: I edited my old answer to show a complete example.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup
  \blx@bblstart
  \input{mybib.bbl}%
  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  % global sorting as this is called at BeginDocument
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}
\makeatother
```

Note that the internal command has been renamed.

You also want to copy a `.bbl` file in the proper format. For `biblatex` 3.7/Biber 2.7 with your settings that is

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,url}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr,lineno}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=nature,date=year,backend=biber,natbib=true,doi=false,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issue}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{isbn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{isbn}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenum}
  {}
  {\printfield{labelnumber}}
  {}
  {}

% define bib resources
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bbl}
\refsection{0}
  \sortlist[entry]{none/global/}
  \entry{A1}{article}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}{%
       family={{\relax PAGES2k Consortium}},
       familyi={{\relax PAGES2k Consortium}\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
  \list{publisher}{1}{%
    {Nature Publishing Group, a division of Macmillan Publishers Limited. All Rights Reserved.}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \strng{fullhash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \strng{authornamehash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \strng{authorfullhash}{6336f16c9082808449bbd32fdb646d7e}
  \field{sortinit}{5}
  \field{sortinithash}{c9df3c9fb8f555dd9201cedc5e343021}
  \field{labelnamesource}{author}
  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{isbn}{1752-0894}
  \field{journaltitle}{Nature Geoscience}
  \field{month}{05}
  \field{number}{5}
  \field{title}{Continental-scale temperature variability during the past two millennia}
  \field{volume}{6}
  \field{year}{2013}
  \field{pages}{339\bibrangedash 346}
  \range{pages}{8}
  \verb{doi}
  \verb 10.1038/ngeo1797
  \endverb
  \verb{url}
  \verb http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ngeo1797
  \endverb
\endentry 
\entry{A2}{online}{}
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}{%
       family={{\relax PAGES 2k Consortium}},
       familyi={{\relax PAGES 2k Consortium}\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \strng{fullhash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \strng{authornamehash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \strng{authorfullhash}{6190cb5961651414f637857f879c5cb3}
  \field{sortinit}{6}
  \field{sortinithash}{02bbed3ed82f61ae046619460488516d}
  \field{labelnamesource}{author}
  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{howpublished}{FigShare}
  \field{title}{A really nice data citation}
  \field{urlyear}{2017}
  \field{urldateera}{ce}
  \verb{doi}
  \verb 10.6084/123.456mwe
  \endverb
  \verb{url}
  \verb https://figshare.com/s/12345678
  \endverb
\endentry 
\endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

%-------------- start insert modified commands ------------------
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup
  \blx@bblstart
  \input{mybib.bbl}%
  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  % global sorting as this is called at BeginDocument
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}
\makeatother
%-------------- end insert modified commands ------------------
\begin{document}
 In this paper, we have regular citations \cite{A1} and data citations \cite{A2}. Both are important.

 % %%%%%%%%%   Citations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\printbibliography[title={References},nottype=online,resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[title={Data citations},type=online,resetnumbers=true]    
 \end{document}
```

Note the `\sortlist[entry]{none/global/}`.

Comment: Thanks much @moewe.  The example compiles perfectly on my system. One quick question: what did mean by "formatted correctly"?  In other words, what was incorrect about my formatting? I ask because the bbl I have is >20,000 lines, so reformatting manually isn't practical. Automated solutions, however, would work.

Comment: @ElNiño Compare the `\sortlist[entry]{none/global/}` from my `.bbl` to the `\sortlist{entry}{nty}` of your `.bbl`. There are two things here: (1) the `.bbl` format changes from version to version, in my version (the most recent 3.7) `entry` is optional, in your example it was not. That caused errors on my machine. `biblatex` can only accept `.bbl` versions that were created by a compatible Biber version. (2) was the sorting, your example specified `nty` in the `.bbl`, but the style you uses requests `none`, so things only work of the sorting in the `.bbl` is `none` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, @moewe.  I got your solution to work with 700 references, copying & pasting from a bbl file generated with the same version of biber. Thanks again for getting me out of this bind.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted another technique that requires less black magic as an answer in [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal)