# Clash JabRef and texstudio

Tags: texstudio, jabref

I am using JabRef and for some bibliography entries, it is reporting a clash

```
Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition. \verb
```

I have already studied this answer [Biblatex: include bbl, problem with “verb” field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166518/biblatex-include-bbl-problem-with-verb-field), but I could not figure out how to implement it with JabRef.

The entry in the .bbl file is like that

```
 \entry{book:464554}{book}{}
\name{author}{1}{}{%
  {{hash=TSJ}{%
     family={Taylor},
     family_i={T\bibinitperiod},
     given={Stephen\bibnamedelima J.},
     given_i={S\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim J\bibinitperiod},
  }}%
}
\strng{namehash}{TSJ1}
\strng{fullhash}{TSJ1}
\field{labelnamesource}{author}
\field{labeltitlesource}{title}
\field{sortinit}{2}
\field{sortinithash}{2}
\field{edition}{2nd}
\field{isbn}{9812770844,9789812770844,9789812770851}
\field{title}{Modelling Financial Times Series}
\verb{url}
\verb
 http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=E14E3D6D5388324EF252FBB2008797
\verb 83
\endverb
\field{year}{2007}
\endentry
```

And when I comment the lines "verb", the problem disappears. However I have to do it manually every time I change the JabRef file (.bib) and it updates the .bbl file.

```
\entry{book:464554}{book}{}
\name{author}{1}{}{%
  {{hash=TSJ}{%
     family={Taylor},
     family_i={T\bibinitperiod},
     given={Stephen\bibnamedelima J.},
     given_i={S\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim J\bibinitperiod},
  }}%
}
\strng{namehash}{TSJ1}
\strng{fullhash}{TSJ1}
\field{labelnamesource}{author}
\field{labeltitlesource}{title}
\field{sortinit}{2}
\field{sortinithash}{2}
\field{edition}{2nd}
\field{isbn}{9812770844,9789812770844,9789812770851}
\field{title}{Modelling Financial Times Series}
%\verb{url}
%\verb
% http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=E14E3D6D5388324EF252FBB2008797
%\verb 83
%\endverb
\field{year}{2007}
\endentry
```

I am using

```
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt,
style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\bibliography{motivacao.bib}
```

My guess would be the problem is associated with the

> @Book entry in the .bib file, because maybe the field "url" should not be there?

As soon as I comment or remove the field from there (JabRef) it works perfectly.

Does anybody have a proper workaround besides deleting or commenting the fault lines?

Thanks!

Comment: For biblatex you need backend=biber, this should resolve your error

Comment: Ideally you would use Biber instead of BibTeX. You will have to change `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber` and run Biber instead of BibTeX, [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) tells you how to do that.

Comment: In fact, the use of  backend=biber produced no error at all. However, it is not referencing correctly. I will try it again and post the result here. Thx anyway!

Comment: If you use `backend=biber` you need to run Biber instead of BibTeX. Have a look at my comment above for help with that.

Comment: Are there any updates here?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't make it work as @moewe kindly suggested.

Comment: What version of `biblatex` do you run? Can you do an update? How did Biber not work for you? Did you read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864? What were the errors or warnings when you tried Biber? What did the `.blg` file say?

Comment: @unmark1 What does `cannot make it work` mean? What errors did you get? Please be more verbose about your problem so that we can diagnose it..

Comment: Any news here? Can you explain exactly what you have tried and how it did not work for you?

Comment: Any news here? As it stands now your question is a duplicate of the one I linked to.