# latexdiff: changes in bibliography with BibLaTeX and Biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, latexdiff

`latexdiff` is able to highlight differences in the bibliography when the content of the `bbl` generated by BibTeX is included in the document.

I've been trying to unsuccessfully do the same with BibLaTeX and Biber, i.e. including the the `bbl` generated by Biber into the document using Herbert's approach [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/11984).

But it does not work. For example, when there is a change in the title of an article, `latexdiff` generates the following:

```
      \DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \field{title}{{Do Consumers Choose the Right Credit Contracts?}}
%DIFDELCMD <       %%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \field{title}{{Does this work? Do Consumers Choose the Right Credit Contracts?}}
      \DIFaddend \field{year}{2006}
```

Which just produces the new title ("Does this work? Do...).

Is there a way to show changes when the bibliography is produced by BibLaTeX and Biber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most situations, including the example you give of a minor change to the title, the following should work

```
latexdiff --append-textcmd=field ...
```

In certain cases, when more extensive changes occur in the bibliography, I could imagine that this will result in doubled  \field{title}  entries (once in the deleted part, and once in the added part). I don't know whether this would cause problems for biber.

Comment: Excellent, this appears to be working! latexdiff should be executed on a bbl that has been generate by biber. Biber is not being used on the bbl that includes the differences.

Comment: @Jörg, I think this is exactly the problem that I am facing here (i.e., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625608/134807). Do you have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 6):

To generate useful diffs on bibliography, one needs to:

- version generated `.bbl` files in addition to bibliography source files,
- use the `--flatten` option to check them out in case you use version control scripts for `latexdiff` such as `latexdiff-git`.

From the [`latexdiff` manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/doc/latexdiff-man.pdf) on `--flatten` option:

> If you use bibtex, it is recommended to include the `.bbl` file in the version management.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a toy example?