# How to use latexdiff to compare changes in .bib files?

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber, latexdiff

I read several of [frederik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38437/frederik)'s answers on `latexdiff`, but I still struggle to get `latexdiff` to mark differences for references (i.e., printed via `\printbibliography`).

Suppose I have two `.tex` and corresponding `.bib` files, all residing in the same folder.

**Old version**

- `old.tex`:

  ```latex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[american]{babel}
  \usepackage[style = apa, backend = biber]{biblatex}
  \usepackage{csquotes}

  % Library settings.
  \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

  % Load the library.
  \addbibresource{old.bib}

  % Main content.
  \begin{document}

  This is a simple citation \cite{hastieElementsStatisticalLearning2009}.

  % References.
  \printbibliography

  \end{document}
  ```
- `old.bib`:

  ```
  @book{hastieElementsStatisticalLearning2009,
      title = {The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction},
      author = {Hastie, Trevor and Tibshirani, Robert and Friedman, Jerome},
      date = {2009},
      edition = {2},
      publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
      url = {https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387848570}
  }
  ```

**New version**

- `new.tex`:

  ```latex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[american]{babel}
  \usepackage[style = apa, backend = biber]{biblatex}
  \usepackage{csquotes}

  % Library settings.
  \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

  % Load the library.
  \addbibresource{new.bib}

  % Main content.
  \begin{document}

  This is an updated citation \cite{hastieElementsStatisticalLearning2009}.

  % References.
  \printbibliography

  \end{document}
  ```
- `new.bib`:

  ```
  @book{hastieElementsStatisticalLearning2009,
      title = {The Elements of Machine Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction},
      author = {Tibshirani, Trevor and Hastie, Robert and Friedman, Jerome},
      date = {2009},
      edition = {2},
      publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
      url = {https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387848570}
  }
  ```

Using `latexdiff`, I would like to see not only the differences in the `.tex` files, but also the differences in the `.bib` files. For instance, the change in author name (i.e., swapped `Hastie` with `Tibshirani`), and the change in the title field (i.e., replaced `Learning` with `Machine` in the title). For clarity, these are the changes between the `.tex` files:

- `old.tex`:

  - `This is a simple citation \cite{hastieElementsStatisticalLearning2009}.`
- `new.tex`:

  - `This is an updated citation \cite{hastieElementsStatisticalLearning2009}.`

And these are the changes between the `.bib` files:

- `old.bib`:

  - `title = {The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction},`
  - `author = {Hastie, Trevor and Tibshirani, Robert and Friedman, Jerome},`
- `new.bib`:

  - `title = {The Elements of Machine Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction},`
  - `author = {Tibshirani, Trevor and Hastie, Robert and Friedman, Jerome},`

To do this, I ran the following commands in the root folder where the `.tex` and `.bib` files are located:

```bash
# Create a `build` directory.
mkdir ./build

# Run `pdflatex` on the `.tex` files to generate `.bcf` files.
pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode old.tex
pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode new.tex

# Run `biber` on the `.bcf` files to generate `.bbl` files.
biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build old.bcf
biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build new.bcf
```

According to [frederik's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172319/134807), I should now run `latexdiff` on the `.bbl` files and produce a `dif.bbl` files with the differences between the `old.bib` and `new.bib` files.

```bash
# Run `latexdiff` on the `.bbl` files.
latexdiff ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl
```

Then, I can go ahead and run `latexdiff` on the actual `.tex` files to produce the `diff.tex` file.

```bash
# Run `latexdiff` on the `.tex` files.
latexdiff old.tex new.tex > ./build/diff.tex
```

Finally, now I have to run `pdflatex` on the `diff.tex` to generate the `.pdf`

```bash
# Run `pdflatex` to produce the `.pdf`.
pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode diff.tex
```

This produces a warning regarding undefined references:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                diff
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

However, the `.pdf` is generated, but the bibliography differences are not being picked up by `latexdiff`, as it can be seen below:

[image: latexdiff output]

If I follow the instructions in the warning and re-run `biber` on `diff.bcf`, the new `diff.bbl` that gets created overrides the previously created `diff.bbl` (i.e., via the command `latexdiff ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl`).

I found [another answer by frederik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167256/134807) where it is recommended to use `--append-textcmd=field` and `--flatten` flags. So I retried the following, which sadly produces exactly the same thing as above:

```bash
# Remove directory.
rm -rf ./build/

# Create a `build` directory.
mkdir ./build

# Run `pdflatex` on the `.tex` files to generate `.bcf` files.
pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode old.tex
pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode new.tex

# Run `biber` on the `.bcf` files to generate `.bbl` files.
biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build old.bcf
biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build new.bcf

# Run `latexdiff` on the `.bbl` files.
latexdiff ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl

# Run `latexdiff` on the `.tex` files with the recommended flags.
latexdiff --append-textcmd=field --flatten old.tex new.tex > ./build/diff.tex

# Run `pdflatex` to produce the `.pdf`.
pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode diff.tex
```

I also followed the instruction from the compiler output and run the following subsequent commands:

```bash
# Run `biber` on the `diff.bcf` to update the `diff.bbl`.
biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build diff.bcf

# Re-run `pdflatex` to re-generate `diff.pdf`.
pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode diff.tex
```

And, again nothing changes, the output is the same:

[image: latexdiff output]

Do you have any ideas oh how I can get `latexdiff` to mark differences in the **References** section, as well as in the citation itself?

---

##### Update (1) based on [frederik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38437/frederik)'s comments

**1. Replacing `\printbibliography` with `\bibliography`:**

- I replaced `\printbibliography` with, for example, `\bibliography{old.bib}` in `old.tex` and it did not work. The file compiled and produced the output, although there was a `! LaTeX Error` in the compiler output. However, neither the citations, nor the references were created.

**2. Replacing `\printbibliography` with the `.bbl` contents**

- this resulted in a fatal error, and no `.pdf` file was produced
- there were a lot of `! Undefined control sequence.` messages (e.g., for `\field`, or `\strng`)

**3. Adding the `--append-textcmd=field` option**

- added the `--append-textcmd=field` when generating the `diff.bbl` using `latexdiff`, i.e.:

  ```bash
  latexdiff --append-textcmd=field ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl
  ```
- removed the `--flatten` option from the `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > ./build/diff.tex`, i.e.:

  ```bash
  latexdiff old.tex new.tex > ./build/diff.tex
  ```
- so, the sequence of commands ran now is:

  ```bash
  # Remove directory.
  rm -rf ./build/

  # Create a `build` directory.
  mkdir ./build

  # Run `pdflatex` on the `.tex` files to generate `.bcf` files.
  pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode old.tex
  pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode new.tex

  # Run `biber` on the `.bcf` files to generate `.bbl` files.
  biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build old.bcf
  biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build new.bcf

  # Create the `diff.bbl` file.
  latexdiff --append-textcmd=field ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl

  # Run `latexdiff` on the `.tex` files with the options removed.
  latexdiff old.tex new.tex > ./build/diff.tex

  # Run `pdflatex` to produce the `.pdf`.
  pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode diff.tex
  ```

And this is already an improvement because now the changes in the bibliography are picked up:

[image: latexdiff improved output]

The compiler output still recommends to rerun `biber` on `diff.bcf` followed by `pdflatex`, but doing that removes all the commands added by `latexdiff` in the `diff.bbl` file.

The only thing not being picked up is the change in the author name. Perhaps the option `--append-textcmd=field` should be adjusted to include something else other than `\field`?

---

##### Update (2)

It seems that adjusting the option `--append-textcmd` does the trick. For example, adjusting it to also include the name:

```bash
latexdiff --append-textcmd="field,name" ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl
```

Produces the following:

[image: latexdiff desired output]

Comment: I don't know biber but will try to give some suggestions: on the second approach with --flatten will not work because latexdiff does not recognise `\printbibliography`, rather it looks for `\bibliography` commands.  Can you replace `\printbibliography` with `\bibliography{...}`?    If this does not work can you try, for testing purposes, to manually replace `\printbibliography` with content of diff.bbl file, and see if it compiles (it would be straightforward to adopt latexdiff to recognise `\printbibliography`) (but see next comment)

Comment: In first approach you would need to add option `--append-textcmd=field` in the command to generate the diff.bbl file, i.e
`latexdiff --append-textcmd=field ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl`

Comment: When using `--flatten` you do not need to generate diff.bbl, by the way, it will be ignored.

Comment: Finally, if the suggestions above do not help, please amend your answer with content of  `old.bbl', `new.bbl` and `diff.bbl`.

Comment: @frederik, thanks for taking a look at this. I am trying right now what you suggested and will report back within a few minutes!

Comment: @frederik, please see my updates based on your suggestions. Things moved forward! Shall I also add the output of the `.bbl` files?

Comment: @frederik, your suggestions helped me nail it down. It seems that the trick was in adding `name` to the `--append-textcmd` option (i.e., `--append-textcmd="field,name"`). Now it works flawlessly (i.e., see **Update (2)** in my question). I will go ahead and create an answer based on your suggestions for others that may be interested. Thanks a lot and `latexdiff` is beautiful!

Comment: @frederik, about your comment on `—flatten` not recognizing `\printbibliography`. Have you seen this? I think this might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/134807.

Comment: very happy that you got this to work in the end, and I encourage you to write up the answer (I guess your update (2) is essentially the answer).  From your failed attempts it seems that \printbibliography  does a lot more than just effectively including the bibliography file (which is what `\bibliography` command effectively does. So implementing this in the `--flatten` option is not as easy as I first thought. Your link in the last comment indeed shows a viable way to implement this but there are more urgent issues, and I will not tackle anytime soon.

Comment: @frederik, I wrote up the answer and also added a bit of context for first-time users. I hope my explanation regarding `--flatten` is correct in the answer. As for implementing it, I totally understand there are more urgent things on the list. I am very happy with `latexdiff` and I even got it to work with `git` via `latexdiff-vc`. It is an amazing tool!

Comment: Can we see changes in bibliography if using ShellEscape in overleaf to see the difference between 2 documents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the setup with the `old.tex` and `new.tex` files provided in the question, the following commands will produce the desired output in a `build` directory.

- create `build` directory

  ```bash
  mkdir ./build
  ```
- run `pdflatex` on each `.tex` file to produce the `.bcf` files

  ```bash
  pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode old.tex
  pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode new.tex
  ```
- run `biber` on each `.bcf` file to produce the `.bbl` files

  ```bash
  biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build old.bcf
  biber --output-directory=build --input-directory=build new.bcf
  ```
- run `latexdiff` on the `.bbl` files to mark the changes

  - ***Note.*** The option `--append-textcmd` is crucial here for `latexdiff` to know what kind of changes we are interested in. We can look inside one of the `.bbl` files to understand how each piece of information is stored. In the question above, the changes are in the title (i.e., `\name{author}`) and author (i.e., `\field{title}`). So, we can add those two to `--append-textcmd` as `--append-textcmd="field,name"`.

  ```bash
  latexdiff --append-textcmd="field,name" ./build/old.bbl ./build/new.bbl > ./build/diff.bbl
  ```
- run `latexdiff` on the `.tex` files to produce a `.tex` file with the changes

  - ***Note.*** If I understand the documentation of `latexdiff` correctly, adding the `--flatten` option to the command below would spare us the need to run `latexdiff` on the `.bbl` files as we did above. With this option, `latexdiff` would replace the `\bibliography{...}` command with the contents of `diff.bbl` (i.e., generated on the fly) in the output `.tex`. However, since we use `biber` as the citation backend, we have `\printbibliography` instead of `\bibliography{...}`. As [frederik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38437/frederik) indicated in the comments above, `latexdiff` is not configured to look for `\printbibliography` commands. We can, in principle, still create a "flat" document by adding the contents of a `.bbl` file manually as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12185/134807).

  ```bash
  latexdiff old.tex new.tex > ./build/diff.tex
  ```
- finally, run `pdflatex` in the `diff.tex` to produce the `.pdf`

  ```bash
  pdflatex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode diff.tex
  ```

The above will result in the marked changes shown below.

[image: latexdiff desired output]