# ! LaTeX Error: Command \c@author already defined

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am close to loose my contenance:
my preamble:

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{bmcart}% uncomment this for twocolumn layout and comment line below
    %%\documentclass{bmcart}

    %%% Load packages
    \usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\usepackage[bmc]{bmc-mathphys}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[latin, german, english]{babel}
    \RequirePackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
    %\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %applemac support if unicode package fails
    %\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %UNIX support if unicode package fails
    \usepackage{dcolumn} %important for tables in the paper!!!)
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
     \usepackage{logreq}
    \usepackage{dcolumn} %for package mtable gotoLatex
    \usepackage{booktabs} %for package mtable
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys}    % Style BST file
    \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %style=authoryear,
    %style=numeric,
    citestyle=numeric,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false, 
    eprint=false, 
    firstinits=true, %adds only initials in bibliography
    terseinits=true, % Removes period after first name intial 
    %dashed=false,
    block=none, %space
    backref=false,
    backrefstyle=three+,
    maxbibnames=99,
    maxcitenames=2,
    hyperref=true,
    sorting=none,
    natbib=true
    ]{biblatex}

    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % Lists all authors with last name first
    %\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1em}
    %\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}

        %\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}} %clears note 

    %   or use Biber settings to eliminate notes and language fildes
    \DeclareSourcemap{
      \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
       \map{
        \step[fieldset=language, null]
         \step[fieldset=notes, null]
          }
        }
      }

        \addbibresource{Rad.bib}        

    \usepackage[hyphenbreaks, anythingbreaks]{breakurl}

    \usepackage{bm} %for bold math added 10.07.2015
    \graphicspath{{Images/}}

\begin{document}
One of the precariously researched areas for example answers to how temporal aspects can influence the economic or clinical result dimension \citep{de_groot_admission_2012}. There is some evidence on how admission days influence outcome (e.g. mortality) or also other dimensions (\citep{concha_variations_2014} \citep{dismuke_has_1999} )

\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}

@article{dismuke_has_1999,
    Author = {Dismuke, Clara E. and Sena, Vania},
    Date = {1999-06-01},
    Date-Modified = {2015-12-14 15:55:00 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1023/A:1019027509833},
    File = {},
    Issn = {1386-9620, 1572-9389},
    Journaltitle = {Health Care Management Science},
    Keywords = {},
    Langid = {english},
    Note = {00072},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {107--116},
    Shortjournal = {Health Care Management Science},
    Shorttitle = {TEST2},
    Url = {http://link.springer.com.ezproxy.unilu.ch/article/10.1023/A%3A1019027509833},
    Urldate = {2014-05-04},
    Volume = {2},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://link.springer.com.ezproxy.unilu.ch/article/10.1023/A%3A1019027509833},
    Bdsk-Url-2 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1019027509833}}

@article{concha_variations_2014,
    Abstract = {},
    Author = {Concha, Oscar Perez and Gallego, Blanca and Hillman, Ken and Delaney, Geoff P. and Coiera, Enrico},
    Date = {2014-03-01},
    Doi = {10.1136/bmjqs-2013-002218},
    File = {},
    Issn = {, 2044-5423},
    Journaltitle = {{BMJ} Quality \& Safety},
    Keywords = {Health services research, Patient Safety, Quality Measurement},
    Langid = {english},
    Note = {00005 {PMID}: 24163392},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {215--222},
    Shortjournal = {{BMJ} Qual Saf},
    Shorttitle = {TEST},
    Url = {http://qualitysafety.bmj.com/content/23/3/215},
    Urldate = {2014-07-09},
    Volume = {23},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://qualitysafety.bmj.com/content/23/3/215},
    Bdsk-Url-2 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1136/bmjqs-2013-002218}}
```

Texstudio generates:

! LaTeX Error: Command \c@author already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

TexShop:
generates document despite the error

How can I avoid the generation of author twice or figure out which package to avoid. TXS a lot!

Comment: It is a bit fishy that you also load `\bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys}` despite the fact that you are using `biblatex`, that could cause other problems further down the road. The real problem seems to be that `bmcart` (at least [this one at github](https://github.com/HongjianLi/tex/blob/master/BMC/bmcart.cls), where did yours come from?) defines `\c@author` itself, so `biblatex` can't use it.

Comment: I was thinking about this too but was not able to figure out how to avoid it. The journal requires the package. Would it not possible to tell [biblatex] to use the [bmcart] definition?

Comment: No, `biblatex`'s `\c@author` is totally different from what `bmcart` does with `c@author`. If you, however, plan to submit to a journal, `biblatex` might not be your best bet after all (see [`biblatex`: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)), especially if they have their house `.bst` file. Have you checked they can accept `biblatex` submissions?

Comment: good point - bmc-mathphys.bst - is what they wish for. it produces a .bbl. i still would wonder whether i can not for trick the system the way i have set i up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class `bmcart` [as found on github](https://github.com/HongjianLi/tex/blob/master/BMC/bmcart.cls) doesn't seem to be perfectly compatible with `biblatex` (there are some `etoolbox` complaints as well).

In particular, it defines a counter `\c@author` which is later also defined by `biblatex`. Those two counters have completely different purposes, so it is not a matter of letting one package use the definition of the other.

We can however simply overwrite the class definition (hoping that this doesn't cause problems down the road) and let `biblatex` do its thing.

```
\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother
```

The following MWE will happily compile with `biblatex`

```
\documentclass[british]{bmcart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}        

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Since the class seems to have its own bibliography package ([github link](https://github.com/HongjianLi/tex/blob/master/BMC/bmcart-biblio.sty)) and a BibTeX styles file ([github link](https://github.com/HongjianLi/tex/blob/master/BMC/bmc-mathphys.bst)) that is probably what you should use when submitting to the journal and not `biblatex` (knowing the [issues that might arise when trying to do so](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)).

Comment: txs... will have a go tonight! i am aware that the \let function might be perilous... will let you know!

Comment: @chrischi If you plan to submit to a journal you should really not do that, you will incapacitate features of the class and not use the bibliography styles they want. (They might not be able to handle `biblatex`.)

Comment: yes you are probably right - i will aim at having a "print" version and a "published" version - probably have to adapt the bbl file too- really appreciate your advice!

Comment: LaTeX is the most beautiful and yet the least user friendly software to use for editting! I wish they had made it a  little simpler.

Comment: How do we find out which package raises the issue if it's not `bmcart`?  In general, I'd prefer to remove the conflicting dependency than add code that code that I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: @JakeStevens-Haas You can comment out packages in your preamble one-by-one and see if the error persists. Work with a copy of your document. Replace the document body by something like `\begin{document}Lorem\end{document}`, then tackle the preamble.