# biblatex instead of natbib in elsarticle, how?

Tags: biblatex, elsarticle

I'm using `elsarticle` and I would like to apply `biblatex` for my references but apparantly `natbib.sty` is loaded by default. In this case how can I use `biblatex` or how can I disable `natbib`?

```
%% natbib.sty is loaded by default. However, natbib options can be
%% provided with \biboptions{...} command. Following options are
%% valid:

%%   round  -  round parentheses are used (default)
%%   square -  square brackets are used   [option]
%%   curly  -  curly braces are used      {option}
%%   angle  -  angle brackets are used    <option>
%%   semicolon  -  multiple citations separated by semi-colon
%%   colon  - same as semicolon, an earlier confusion
%%   comma  -  separated by comma
%%   numbers-  selects numerical citations
%%   super  -  numerical citations as superscripts
%%   sort   -  sorts multiple citations according to order in ref. list
%%   sort&compress   -  like sort, but also compresses numerical citations
%%   compress - compresses without sorting
%%
%% \biboptions{comma,round}

% \biboptions{}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=authoryear 
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
 bla bla bla 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Messages/Log file: `Command \bibhang already defined,`

Comment: From your code it's impossible to say: presumably something earlier is loading `natbib`

Comment: Welcome. Sorry, but that is not your decision. The journal has its workflow and they are using `natbib`. Maybe it will be different in the future, who knows?

Comment: Well, that's sad, but thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: There is `\RequirePackage[\@biboptions]{natbib}` inside of `elsarticle.cls`.

Answer (score 9):

According to [the documentation](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf#section.4) of the last release of `elsarticle`, option `nonatbib` can be used. However,

```
\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother
```

is needed according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283218/2288) to get rid of the following error:

> Command \c@author already defined. \abx@donames.

```
\documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=true,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents,hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Fornberg2008,
    author =    {Fornberg, Bengt and Piret, Cécile},
    title =     {On choosing a radial basis function and a shape parameter when solving a convective PDE on a sphere},
    journal =   {Journal of Computational Physics},
    year =      {2008},
    volume =    {227},
    number =    {5},
    pages =     {2758-2780},
    month =     {feb},
    doi =       {10.1016/j.jcp.2007.11.016},
    issn =      {0021-9991},
    publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
    type =      {Journal Article},
    url =       {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2007.11.016}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum~\cite{Fornberg2008}.

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine! Thank you! But is there also a way to accomplish this with the harvard template and citation style?

Comment: @xyz I think your question has an answer in the documentation of biblatex.

Comment: `@Diaa` what do you mean by that? There is no harvard citation style in biblatex. I wondered, because biblatex can't use the cst file attached to the elsarticle template.

Comment: @xyz I have no idea. I just presumed.

Answer (score 7):

### This solution must only be used for typesetting personal notes!

---

### Do not submit your papers like this!

---

### If you consider submitting your papers with this hack in place, please stop reading right now!

---

### For academic use only

---

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\typeout{Please don't do this for journal submission}]{natbib}
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\expandafter\let\csname c@author\endcsname=\relax
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{aristotle:physics}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This breaks with the ´3p´ or ´5p´ options to ´elsarticle´. Any suggestions?

Comment: @flindeberg Considering the warnings, i would recommend not to use stuff like that.

Comment: I'm not questioning the stupidity of doing it, I'm asking how to do it. Anyhow I solved it, and will link when I'm at a computer again.

Comment: Hi @flindeberg, Could you give us a clue how you solved it? Since the logos do not found: elsevier-logo-0p, SDlogo-0p, I tried to put this name's file in my directory, but my title is not aligned.

Comment: @Oromion Added an answer, hope it solves the issues. If not just comment on my answer!

Answer (score 6):

### This solution must only be used for typesetting personal notes!

---

### Do not submit your papers like this!

---

### If you consider submitting your papers with this hack in place, please stop reading right now!

---

Sometimes the macros defined by the journal documentclasses come in handy for typesetting personal notes.  For such private documents however one also wants to exploit the convenience of modern package such as `biblatex`.

The `elsarticle` documentclass loads `natbib` internally which is a show stopper for `biblatex`.  The `natbib` package is loaded with the line

```
\RequirePackage[\@biboptions]{natbib}
```

To this end, hacking into `\RequirePackage` and make it just skip over `natbib` would solve the problem at hand.  I use the `xparse` package and the underlying `expl3` programming layer to realise such a macro.  The (re)definition of such a macro obviously has to be placed *before* `\documentclass`.

Furthermore, `elsarticle` defines a counter called `author`, which is never used by the class but required by `biblatex`.  We simply undefine the counter by letting its underlying count variable to `\relax`.

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \pkg_ignored_clist
\clist_put_right:Nn \pkg_ignored_clist { natbib }

\msg_new:nnn { pkg } { pkg-ignored } { Package~#1~ignored! }

\cs_set_eq:NN \latex_require_package:wnw \RequirePackage

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pkg_require_package:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \IfValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \IfValueTF { #3 }
     { \latex_require_package:wnw [ #1 ] { #2 } [ #3 ] }
     { \latex_require_package:wnw [ #1 ] { #2 }        }
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF { #3 }
     { \latex_require_package:wnw { #2 } [ #3 ] }
     { \latex_require_package:wnw { #2 }        }
   }
 }

\RenewDocumentCommand \RequirePackage { o m o }
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \pkg_ignored_clist { #2 }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { pkg } { pkg-ignored } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \pkg_require_package:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{elsarticle}
\expandafter\let\csname c@author\endcsname=\relax
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\Citet{weinberg}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@Oromion asked how I solved it for `3p` and `5p` so putting an MWE here. Do note that this is not for publications, and I did it after a couple of students requested help since they had been asked to write an "Elsevier style paper" for a course.

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

%% Fix so biblatex works instead of natbib
\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax

%% Fix headers and footers
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
    \let\@oddhead\@empty
    \let\@evenhead\@empty
    \def\@oddfoot{}%
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

%% Load some packages and stuff

%% Library and stuff
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%% biblatex with apa-style.
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{library}

%% Rest as usual....
```

Comment: Please Is there any other options to achieve that for publications?