# Issue with biblatex: bibhang already defined

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, achemso

I am trying to convert my document from bibtex to biblatex to use some of the new features there.

I get this error:

! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.

I assume that this is caused by a conflict between biblatex and one of my other packages but I have not been able to find it.

This is an example with the packages I am using:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{usetitle=true}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage{dcolumn}    
\usepackage{subfigure}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{xr}    
\usepackage{placeins}    
\usepackage{setspace}    
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,maxbibnames=100]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\externaldocument{supporting-info}

\title{Title of my paper}

\author{Name}    
\affiliation{University}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

text text text

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I tried to delete the lines referring to natbib from the achemso.sty file, but that did not resolve the issue.

From achemso.sty:

```
    %%\AtBeginDocument{
%%  \def\nmv@natbib@detect{%
%%    \ifNAT@super
%%      \expandafter\acs@nmv@activate
%%   \else
%%      \expandafter\acs@autonote
%%    \fi
%%  }
%%}

\ifacs@super
  %%\RequirePackage[sort&compress,numbers,super]{natbib}
\else
  %%\RequirePackage[sort&compress,numbers,round]{natbib}
  \def\citenumfont{\textit}
\fi
```

Edit: I should note that the program does produce a PDF but it gives me an error that I am trying to remove.

Comment: Welcome! If the journal tells you to use this class, they are unlikely to tolerate your use of Biblatex. If you aren't submitting to such a journal, use a class which doesn't impose a journal's house style on your document. Note that `subfigure` is obsolete and ought not be used.

Comment: Note that you are using the `.cls` file which loads `natbib`. Also note that you should not change any of these files without renaming them. That is, copy the file to a new name and edit that, if you wish. You should not edit the files in place or under their original names.

Comment: You are in general not allowed to change files you do not own. You cannot just remix your favourite Shakira song as well without getting into copyright trouble.

Comment: If you ware going to submit to ACS, you can't use `biblatex`. Just use the `achemso` package and the bundled `.bst` files for BibTeX. See http://pubs.acs.org/page/4authors/submission/tex.html and https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso

Answer (score 5):

You are using the `achemso` document class. That class loads `natbib`, which is incompatible with `biblatex`.

If you want to submit to the ACS you should not use `biblatex`, you should use the `.bst` style that comes bundled with `achemso` (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso).

If you do not plan to submit and just want to use this for your personal documents, you need a way to stop `achemso.cls` from loading `natbib`. This should be doable with the approaches from [biblatex instead of natbib in elsarticle, how?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321989/35864). You should not modify `achemso.cls` directly. But if you don't plan to submit to the ACS, you could also simply use another document class.