# Problem with bibliography creation, LaTeX template for a Wiley journal

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cite-package

I am using a template provided by Wiley for one of their journals which has its own document class and everything else as per requirement. There are two issues I'm facing:

1. I cannot generate a bibliography using bibtex: The error is incompatible package \cite.
2. Even after moving files to local texmf directory and refreshing FNDB I get the bibliography style not found error.

I know why the incompatible \cite error occurs and as seen in my code i have not used `\usepackage{cite}` anywhere. As for the second error, I have already stated that I have moved relevant .sty and .bts files to root and texmf directories.

How can I fix this?!

Here's my document preamble:

```
\documentclass{prop2015}% no class options needed by now
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=prop]{biblatex}
%\bibliographystyle{prop}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
```

Comment: Please show us a short compilable code we can test on our own computer. Do not forget to add the used bib entries resulting in errors. Welcome to TeX.SE! And do you have a link to your used class?

Comment: The instruction `\bibliographystyle` presupposes the use of BibTeX, to create the formatted bibliography. However, you seem to also want to use the `biblatex` package with the `biber` backend, not BibTeX. For sure, the `cite` and `biblatex` packages are mutually incompatible. Which method are you supposed to be using -- BibTeX or biber?  Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I just checked in the guide for the template it was advised to use `\bibliographystyle{prop}` and
`\bibliography{<databasefilename>}`. And then to run through bibtex.

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't be using the `biblatex` package at all. Instead, be sure to run latex, then bibtex, and finally latex twice more to generate (a) the formatted bibliography and (b) the in-text citation call-outs.

Comment: I just did that and received the error `Missing 'biblatex' package.`

Comment: after removing the usepackage biblatex you should also delete the `.aux` file and allow a new non-biblatex one to be generated.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466203/35864 for a different Wiley class and linked/related questions for other publisher classes. Usually publisher classes use BibTeX (maybe with `cite` or `natbib`) and are strictly incompatible with `biblatex`. Publisher `.bst` files can't be used with `biblatex`, either (`style=prop` should fail unless you have a `biblatex` style called prop residing in `prop.bbx` and `prop.cbx`). Remove `biblatex` and all of its commands and then delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) and recompile.

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: @Mico Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so we can mark this question as resolved?

Comment: @moewe - Done. :-)

Comment: @Mico Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tagged this query with both `cite-package` and `biblatex`. Unfortunately for you, the `cite` and `biblatex` packages are mutually incompatible.

To use the `cite` package, you must also (a) provide a suitable `\bibliographystyle` instruction and (b) run BibTeX. To use the `biblatex` package, you must (i) *not* load the `cite` package, (ii) use `biber` rather than BibTeX, and (iii) replace the single instruction `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` with two instructions: insert `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` in the preamble (*after* loading the `biblatex` package), and insert `\printbibliography` in the document in the location where the formatted bibliography is supposed to be inserted.

I'm not aware of the existence of a ready-made biblatex style called `prop`. Given your comment that you were "advised to use `\bibliographystyle{prop}` and `\bibliography{<databasefilename>}`, [a]nd then to run through bibtex," I will assume that you really do need to use the `cite` package with BibTeX as the back-end, rather than the `biblatex` package with the `biber` back-end.

If the good folks who provide the LaTeX document class file `prop2015.cls` also provide a bibliography style file called `prop.bst`, and if the raw bibliographic entries are contained in a file called `bibliography.bib`, you should thus proceed as follows.

- First, reorganize your document so that its structure resembles the following layout:

  ```
  \documentclass{prop2015}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  %%\usepackage[english]{babel} % Don't load packages more than once
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  %%\usepackage{amsfonts} % Is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{breqn}

  \usepackage{cite} % the package called "cite"
  \bibliographystyle{prop}

  \usepackage{hyperref} % this package must be loaded _last_

  \begin{document}
  %% ... various \cite instructions ...
  \bibliography{bibliography} % don't use the ".bib" extension here
  \end{document}
  ```

  (Aside: Do please make a habit of not trying to load packages more than once.)
- Second, once the document compiles without syntax errors, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the main tex file. Doing so will create (a) the formatted bibliography and (b) the numeric-style citation call-outs to the bib entries in the body of the document.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply! This worked.