# "nonatbib" & "5p" conflict using elsarticle.cls

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib, elsarticle

I want to use the `biblatex` instead of `natbib` with the `elsarticle` class. There is an option to that (with `nonatibib`) according to [elsarticle.cls](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc/elsdoc.pdf) documentation.

The problem came when I want to use it with the `3p` and `5p` options (which they allow to use double-column style).

I have seen a solution with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437358/165284) answer, but

- it has been done without the `nonatbib` option,
- and it is not recommended to be used in a publication.

However, I want to use it for publication.

here is my working example:

```
\documentclass[nonatbib,5p,twocolumn]{elsarticle} 

\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}     
      hello world!
\end{document}
```

the 3 lines in the preamble have been added according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283218/2288) but  I still get this error

> Undefined control sequence. \global\bibsep
>
> You can't use a prefix with `the character ='. \global\bibsep=
>
> Missing \begin{document}. \global\bibsep=

Comment: Note that **no** solution that lets you use `biblatex` with `elsarticle` is recommended for publication (unless Elsevier editors specifically tell you otherwise): `elsarticle` uses `natbib` and includes matching `.bst` styles for a reason. The workflow for `biblatex` is quite different than the workflow with a classic BibTeX bibliography. Very few publishers accept `biblatex`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864.

Comment: I only just read the "However, I want to use it for publication.", so I added this warning to my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

> **Warning!** Unless Elsevier editors or journal staff explicitly tell you otherwise, **I strongly recommend *against* using `biblatex` for submissions to Elsevier** (with `elsearticle` or any other class). `elsarticle` loads `natbib` and includes matching BibTeX styles for a reason. The workflow for `biblatex` is quite different than the workflow with a classic BibTeX bibliography. In general very few publishers accept `biblatex`. See also [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864).
>
> Just use `natbib` and one of the styles recommended in the bibliography. It is unlikely you will need any of `biblatex`'s advanced features to satisfy journal requirements. And adding fancy stuff that is not common in publications in that journal might not be a great idea anyway (journals like consistency).

## Caveat emptor

There are three instances of

```
\global\bibsep=0pt
```

in `elsarticle.cls`.

Unfortunately, these lines fail with the error you describe, when `\bibsep` is not defined. Usually `\bibsep` is defined by `natbib`, but since the MWE doesn't load that package (thanks to `nonatbib`) the length ends up being undefined.

If the class supports not loading `natbib` with `nonatbib` it should probably make guard assignments to `\bibsep` to make sure it only uses the macro when it is actually defined.

**This should be reported as a bug to the `elsarticle` maintainers.**

In the meantime the following MWE compiles fine again

```
\newlength{\bibsep}
\documentclass[nonatbib,5p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  hello world!
\end{document}
```

since the `\newlength{\bibsep}` makes sure the length is defined.

Comment: My reason of wanting to use `biblatex` instead of `natbib` is the amount of freedom you have with `biblatex's` options, especially disabling the `url` option that I strongly need. Although there are some solutions that deals with this using the `natbib` package, but they are kind of "tweeks" and not "a really stable solution". Therefore, It seems that I have to stick with using `natbib` any way!