# SIAM bibliography style for BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I am searching for a SIAM bibliography style for BibLaTeX. This style does [exist for Bibtex](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base), but I was unable to find something similar for BibLaTeX.

An example of the SIAM Bibtex style can be found [here](https://sharelatex-wiki-cdn-671420.c.cdn77.org/learn-scripts/images/4/4d/BibtexStylesEx7.png). If no such style exist for BibLaTeX, I am also interested in styles close to the SIAM style.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  May I ask what you have tried so far? What is the reason you need SIAM style? Rule of your university? Are you then allowed to use `biblatex` and `biber`? Please explain better what the problem is ...

Comment: The problem is: If you are submitting to SIAM you probably can't use `biblatex`, they will most likely enforce BibTeX. (Ask them before you get started with anything.) In any way, there probably is no direct SIAM style for `biblatex`. So you will have to find a style that is similar. A starting point would be the `numeric` style family. You then modify the styles to your needs.

Comment: I need the style for a publication. Thanks for pointing out, that I should ask if i can use biblatex at SIAM. However, it seems, that the conference is just using the PDFs (the publications of recent proceedings are very different in their style and compiled with different tools). Biblatex is needed to use more than a single bib file.

Comment: BibTeX also supports multiple `.bib` files. If that is all you need `\bibliography{fileone,filetwo}` should work just fine with BIbTeX (incidentally AFAIK that exact line does not work with `biblatex`). Or do you mean to do more fancy stuff with that?

Comment: Thank you for the efford, one problem less with Bibtex ;-) However, it is also very easy to remove some fields in biblatex (e.g. url, doi). AFAIK i need to modify the style in bibtex to accomplish this. Furthermore, I have used  the \citet command with numerical style in biblatex (this gives me errors in bibtex).

Comment: Yes, you would have to modify the `.bst` to remove the fields. But if the the SIAM style prints them, there is a good reason for that: They probably want it that way. The `\citet` thingy is a different problem though, often numeric styles don't like `\citet`. But: Do SIAM publications cite like that? Or do they always use the number only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to submit to SIAM, you should consider using their templates for that. That will probably cause the least hassle for all parties involved. (See also [`biblatex`: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)) If you don't write for a SIAM publication, rethink if you *really* need to use SIAM style or if you can live with a style that looks similar.

AFAIK there is no SIAM style for `biblatex`, so you will have to roll your own. Start from the standard style that comes closest to what you need. (You can also start from other custom styles, some of them are harder to customise than others, though; the standard styles are always easy to modify.)

That is probably going to be `style=numeric`. Then start emulating the features you need. A good start is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864), but you will find help for many more issues on this site.

From the picture I saw, I went with

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\newbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{publisher}}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{institution}}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{organization}}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a,sigfridsson,worman,geer,companion,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Of course this captures only parts of the style, and only parts of what I could see in the example picture you posted.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Looks good. I cannot vote for you as i do not have 15 rep, but i will do so as soon it happened.

Comment: My strategy with journals is to submit the paper in PDF formatted from tex source designed according to my very own style.  When (and if) the paper is accepted, I revert the latex to the journal's style.  One nice thing about latex is that (if written properly) one can separate contents from formatting and all changes to macros can be done in half an afternoon (usually, the fact that the paper has been accepted boosts one's productivity).