# Using citation alphabetical citation style with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I am using the `biblatex-chicago` package for my documents.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
```

However, now I would like the citations to follow a certain format: first 4 letters from the author's name followed by the last 2 digits of the publication's year, e.g. `[Knut68]` for The Art of Computer Programming
by Donald Knuth.

How can I achieve this with `biblatex-chicago`?

Comment: `biblatex-chicago` does not support an alphabetic style, you would have to switch to normal `biblatex` with `style=alphabetic`: `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`. But of course then your bibliography will look quite different.

Comment: Any news here? I'm still not entirely sure what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @moewe - well, let's say that I'm trying to negotiate the requirements for a couple of papers I'm writing. In my scenario listing the bibliography in Chicago style is enouraged but also citations in the format I mentioned.

Comment: What do they mean by "Chicago style" though, could you get away just with the normal `style=alphabetic` from `biblatex`? Note that many journals have their own work flows and cannot accept papers with a `biblatex` bibliography (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)). So you should really check with them beforehand if they can accept `.tex` files using `biblatex`, and ask if they have some kind of template or ready-made bibliography style. Maybe they already have that.