# Customize Biblatex APA style for proceedings

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am using Biblatex with APA-style, and I would like to change the way "in proceedings" references are displayed, from

Authors (year). Title. In *Proceedings* (pp. A-B)

to

Authors (year). Title. In *Proceedings*, pp. A-B

since the journal I'm submitting to requires this style.
Any idea how to do so?

EDIT:

Here's a MWE.

`test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\bibliography{test}
\begin{document}
\cite{twitter}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`test.bib`

```
@inproceedings{twitter,
author = {Kwak, Haewoon and Lee, Changhyun and Park, Hosung and Moon, Sue},
title = {What is {Twitter}, a Social Network or a News Media?},
booktitle = {{International World Wide Web Conference}},
year = {2010},
pages = {591--600},
}
```

I assume that proceedings entries only contain `author`, `title`, `booktitle`, `year`, and `pages` fields, as in the MWE.

Comment: Please help us to help you by providing an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that we can play around with. That way you can make sure that the answers you get are tested with your set-up.

Comment: Please have a look at [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). Depeding on the workflow of the journal you plan to submit to you might not be able to use `biblatex` at all. If of course you only submit a PDF you are fine.

Comment: A bit of research reveals that `biblatex-apa` would also put additional information into the same pair of brackets. `edition`, `chapter`, `volume` and `number` will also appear there if present. What do you want to do about those fields? Do they still appear in brackets, or do they also lose the bracketing? (Just add `edition = {3}` to an example entry and check the output, then report the expected output.)

Comment: Edited my original question with MWE. I also assume that those fields are not present, only the `pages` field is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you still want all other information that could appear in the same pair of brackets placed in brackets, go with

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\renewbibmacro*{addinfo}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{edition}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{chapter}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{volumes}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{number}\AND%
              \(\iffieldundef{volume}\OR\boolean{bbx:volseen}\)}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibopenparen}%
   \printfield{edition}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{chapter}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \notbool{bbx:volseen}%
     {\iffieldundef{volume}{}{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \iffieldundef{part}{}{\printfield{part}}}{}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{number}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{volumes}%
   \setunit{}%
   \printtext{\bibcloseparen}%
   \newunit}
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pages}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,moraux,salam}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This just moves the page printing outside the brackets.

Comment: This works fine, except that it doesn't print the comma after the title. Changing `\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}` to `\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}` solves the problem (don't know if it's the "right" thing to do, though).

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa Ah yes, sorry. I must have posted the wrong version of the code. The unstarred version is indeed the correct way to achieve this. The answer has been updated.