# Adding "references.bib" on my .tex produces an Error: Command \bibhang already defined. Removing it, compiles the file perfectly!

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors

This is My 1st try to produce an Article-Like document.

[Here's](https://www.aanda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=129&Itemid=173) the format I have followed,  and the sample text worked perfectly!!

The bibliography tho, was added not in the way I liked it; I used to add  bibliography like this;

```
@ARTICLE{2016MNRAS.457.1722R,
  author = {{Rieder}, M. and {Teyssier}, R.},
  title = "{A small-scale dynamo in feedback-dominated galaxies as the origin of cosmic magnetic fields - I. The kinematic phase}",
  journal = {\mnras},
  archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint = {1506.00849},
  keywords = {MHD, turbulence, methods: numerical, galaxies: magnetic fields},
  year = 2016,
  month = apr,
  volume = 457,
  pages = {1722-1738},
  doi = {10.1093/mnras/stv2985},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016MNRAS.457.1722R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

To follow that, I went to my "Thesis" tex and copied what was there;

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and on the end of the .tex:

```
\printbibliography
```

and of course I copied references.bib on my folder.

Those two, results on the following Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help. ...                                                  
l.462 \newlength{\bibhang}
```

I tried to follow some other similar questions, but couldn't fine any  commands like these;

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
\RequirePackage{natbib}
```

on any of my files.

EDIT: Here is part of my code:

```
\documentclass{aa}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `aa.cls` loads `natbib` which defines `\bibhang`. `biblatex` also defines `\bibhang`. You can't use `natbib` and `biblatex`. They are totally different ways of handling references.

Comment: also you can format code blocks by indenting 4 spaces. You can do this automatically by highlighting your code block and pressing `ctrl+k`

Comment: @DavidPurton any Idea on how to fix this? I want to use biblatex. Also, thanks for the info! Fixed it!

Comment: If you want to submit, it is quite unlikely that they will accept `biblatex`. Especially since their class mandates `natbib`. See [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). And if you don't want to submit to their journal, why do you use their class in the first place?

Comment: You got a point! Ty for your info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting to the journal they will probably not accept `biblatex`, but if you just want to use `biblatex` with `aa.cls` and not submit to the journal then you can load the class with the `bibyear` option which does not load `natbib`. (I don't know what other side effects this may have, but you can probably work around them.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[bibyear]{aa}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{2016MNRAS.457.1722R,
  author = {Rieder, M. and Teyssier, R.},
  title = {A small-scale dynamo in feedback-dominated galaxies as the origin of cosmic magnetic fields - I. The kinematic phase},
  journal = {\mnras},
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprint = {1506.00849},
  keywords = {MHD, turbulence, methods: numerical, galaxies: magnetic fields},
  year = {2016},
  month = {4},
  volume = {457},
  pages = {1722-1738},
  doi = {10.1093/mnras/stv2985},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016MNRAS.457.1722R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite[1722]{2016MNRAS.457.1722R}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, REALLY thank you! I didn't know `biblatex` was not acceptable. I guess I have to find out how `natbib` works. Much useful information! Up-voted and Accepted