# Get Biblatex to show URL for Webpage references

Tags: biblatex, urls

I'm currently using Mendeley to gather my references and export them as a `.bib` file. I turned off the URL parameters on inclusion of Biblatex as I don't want URLs for published papers, books, etc:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric,
            sorting=none,
            url=false]{biblatex}
```

However, I want the URLs in my references for webpages. I realise that one solution is to just remove the URLs from Mendeley before exporting to `.bib`, but I also want to keep the URLs there for published works.

Comment: For your webpages, you should use `@online`, for which the `url` is always printed, even with `url=false`. I'm not a Mendeley user though, so I'm not sure about how to tell it to do that. Anyway, that's what `biblatex` would expect.

Comment: Welcome! That will work, provided you are using appropriate entry types, as @gusbrs notes and provided, of course, that Mendeley includes the data in the exported `.bib`. If Mendeley is using the wrong entry type for web pages, that's where you need to intervene in your workflow.

Comment: Chances are that Mendeley exports webpages as `@misc` or as a weird entrytype that `biblatex` does not know and therefore maps to `@misc`. As gusbrs and cfr already pointed out, if you have an `@online` you should get to see the URL even with `url=false`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I didn't realise but Mendeley is exporting webpage references as `@misc` instead of `@online`. I can't seem to find a way of changing this. Mendeley's auto `.bib` syncing is very useful, but it looks like I'm just going to have to manually change the `@misc` to `@online` before submission.

Comment: Maybe you should consider complaining to the Mendeley people. They really should export `@online` if they want to support `biblatex`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422563/35864 has a work-around to reclassify `@misc`s with URL as `@online`.

Answer (score 12):

The standard behaviour of `biblatex` is to always display URLs for `@online` regardless of the `url` option. So even with `url=false` you should see the URL of `@online` entries.

Mendeley exports websites as `@misc` entries. But `@misc` does not fall under the `@online` exception above and so the URLs of your sources are suppressed.

**The solution is to tell the Mendeley people that they should export online sources to `@online` if they want to support `biblatex` properly.** I have googled around a bit and it seems like people have been trying to get Mendeley to change their `.bib` export for quite a while, apparently with limited success.

You can use a method similar to [Mendeley and Biblatex: how to interpret 'misc' as 'patent' or 'online'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422563/35864) to try and salvage your `.bib` file. The map

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url, final]
      \step[typesource=misc, typetarget=online]
    }
  }
}
```

converts all `@misc`s with a URL field to `@online`.

The map

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[typesource=misc, typetarget=online]
    }
  }
}
```

converts all `@misc`s to `@online`.

Both solutions assume that you have no legitimate `@misc` entries with a `url` field (which should not be converted to `@online`).

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @OliverCrow But don't rely on this workaround. Pressure the Mendeley people into implementing a proper `.bib` export.

Comment: I have sent them a message about this (through their contact methods). Their Feature Requests page just returns a 404...

Comment: Great answer, second snippet worked for me perfectly

Comment: I have the attached `@online` bib item and use `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and it doesn't show the URL. Any ideas?


`@online{eip,
title = {{The Electoral Integrity Project}},
url = {https://www.electoralintegrityproject.com}
}`

Comment: @pms `plain` is a very old BibTeX style (not `biblatex`, as in this question). It was written before URLs were a big thing. That's why it doesn't support a `url` field. You need to choose a style that does. You could try `plainurl` instead of `plain` or one of the `natbib` styles.