# Add 'urldate' to bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, mendeley

I'm using `biblatex` with a custom bibstyle based on the [`trad-standard`](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-trad/blob/master/trad-standard.bbx) style:

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{trad-standard}
```

In my custom style I redefined some appearances like bold text etc. but now I want to add the `urldate` to the output if a URL is given.

I have for example a website as reference. Mendeley exported the resource as `@misc` which seems to be correct, but the access date (saved as `urldate`) is not showing up.
I now searched the code of the `trad-standard` bibstyle and didn't find the `urldate` key, so it's quite logical that there is no output. How could I add the functionality of always displaying the `urldate`, if a URL and the `urldate` is given, no matter what entry type I'm in?

My guess is to renew the `doi+eprint+url` macro as it is responsible for the output of the URL. So if I could append the `urldate` to the output, it should do what I want. The problem is, that I have no idea how tho append the `urldate` to the macro.

---

Here is my custom `.bbx` file:

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a custom bibliography style based on the trad-abbrv style
% by Marco Daniel (2012--2015) and Moritz Wemheuer (2016--).
%
% This package is released under the terms of the
% LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
% See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%
% Copyright (c) 2012 -- 2015 Marco Daniel
%               2016 --      Moritz Wemheuer
%
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Declare Style
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesFile{custom-abbrv.bbx}[2017/10/18 v1.0.0 Custom abbrv Bibliography Style]



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Require Styles
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequireBibliographyStyle{trad-standard}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Basic Options
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    abbreviate      = false,
    arxiv           = false
    autolang        = hyphen,
    backref         = false,
    dateabbrev      = true,
    eprint          = false,
    hyperref        = true,
    labelnumber     = true,
    maxnames        = 3,
    minnames        = 3,
    sorting         = none,
}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% trad-abbrv Settings
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2016/03/01}{%
    \@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2016/05/14}{%
        \DeclareNameFormat{abbrv}{%
            \usebibmacro{name:given-family}%
            {\namepartfamily}%
            {\namepartgiveni}%
            {\namepartprefixi}%
            {\namepartsuffixi}%
            \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
        }%
    }{%
        \DeclareNameFormat{abbrv}{%
            \nameparts{#1}%
            \usebibmacro{name:given-family}%
            {\namepartfamily}%
            {\namepartgiveni}%
            {\namepartprefixi}%
            {\namepartsuffixi}%
            \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
        }%
    }%
}{%
    \DeclareNameFormat{abbrv}{%
        \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}%
        \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
    }%
}%
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{abbrv}


\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}


\@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2016/05/14}{%
    \defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
        {%
            \list{%
                \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
                    \printfield{labelprefix}%
                    \printfield{labelnumber}%
                }%
            }{%
                \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
                \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
                \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
                \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
                \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
                \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
            }%
            \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}%
        }
        {\endlist}
        {\item}%
}{%
    \defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
        {%
            \list{%
                \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
                    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
                    \printfield{labelnumber}%
                }%
            }{%
                \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
                \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
                \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
                \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
                \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
                \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
            }%
            \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}%
        }%
        {\endlist}%
        {\item}%
}

\defbibenvironment{shorthands}%
    {%
        \list{%
            \printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}%
        }{%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
            \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}%
        }%
    }%
    {\endlist}%
    {\item}%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}%
    {%
        \entryset%
        {%
            \ifbool{bbx:subentry}%
                {%
                    \printfield[bibentrysetcount]{entrysetcount}%
                    \setunit*{\addnbspace}%
                }%
                {}%
        }%
        {}%
        \newunit\newblock%
        \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
        \finentry%
    }



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Appearance Styles
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Name
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

% Title
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\enquote{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},}

% Volume
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1}

% Number
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Pages
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\space#1\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}

% Year
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\textbf{#1}}

% URL
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL:\space\url{#1}}

% ISSN / ISBN
\DeclareFieldFormat{issn}{ISSN:\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{ISBN:\space\url{#1}}

% DOI
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    DOI\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
        {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
        {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
}

% Item Separation
\setlength\bibitemsep{.5\baselineskip}

% Alignment
\AtBeginBibliography{\raggedright}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Changes in the position
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Change the position of the year to be in front of the volume
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \usebibmacro{date}% Added the date, right after the journal
    \newcommaunit*%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {%
        \newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    }%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+pages+eid}%
    \newcommaunit
    % \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date-parens}%
    \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit%
}

% Remove the date after the volume
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date-parens}{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}%
    {%
        % \usebibmacro{date}
    }%
    {%
        \printfield{issue}%
        \newcommaunit*%
        % \usebibmacro{date}
    }%
    \newunit%
}

\endinput
```

Comment: I think it is simpler. Does this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428959/105447 help?

Comment: Can you give an example (i.e. an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)), please? The unmodified `biblatex-trad` styles always display URLs and URL dates for all entry types. If you or your customisation set the `url=false` option, you will get URLs and URL dates for only `@online` entries (all other types don't display URLs then). If you see a different behaviour even with an explicit `url=true`, your custom style modifies `trad-standard` in a way that it destroys the standard behaviour.

Comment: @gusbrs That looks great, but unfortunately it has no effect on my output.

Comment: @moewe URL is set to `true` and even if I change `@misc` to `@online` no date is output.

Comment: Mhhh, the code looks OK and in fact works for me in a short document I created (see https://gist.github.com/moewew/4e100b2a1f044354ba07927ea6cfac6a). Can you show us a complete example along the line of my link, please? We need to see an example `.bib` file and how you load your custom style in your document.

Comment: @moewe I found the problem. Mendeley exports my date, that is saved as `2018-04-30` in Mendeley, as `30.04.2018` to the `.bib` file. If I manually change it back to `2018-04-30`, the output works just fine. Have you an idea how I could change the date format inside the `.bbx` file?

Comment: Maybe you should rework/edit your question so it describes the actual problem more accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out in the comments, the problem is actually a malformed `urldate` field as exported by Mendeley. All `biblatex` date fields must be written in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (ISO 8601/EDTF), `DD.MM.YYYY` is not acceptable input and generates a warning:

> ```
> Invalid format '30.04.2018' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
> ```

You should definitely contact the Mendeley developers about this.

In the meantime, here is a fix with Biber's sourcemapping

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
  url     = {http://example.com/~sirhumphrey/cc.pdf},
  urldate = {30.04.2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=urldate, match=\regexp{\A(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})\Z}, replace={$3-$2-$1}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

But don't just use it: Complain to the Mendeley people!