# Mendeley creates wrong bibtex for website

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, overleaf, mendeley

I'm using Mendeley to manage all my references and include them to overleaf over the `bibtex` import.
Usually that works fine, but I figured out that the website references are displayed wrongly.

In Mendelay I fill in the Type "Web Page", The company (author) of the site, the URL and access date.

The `bibtex` arriving in Overleaf is the following:

```
@misc{IBMScramblingData,
  title = {{Scrambling data}},
  author = {{IBM}},
  url = {https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXJAV_14.1.0/com.ibm.filemanager.doc_14.1/db2/copyscramb.html?cp=SS7EY3_3.1.0}
}
```

As you can see, the access date is completely missing, also it used `@misc` instead of `@online`.

Anyone an idea on how to fix this?

PS: I'm using  `biblatex` and `biber` using the `apa` style. But they can't produce it correctly without having the info in the file.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428959/35864 can help.

Comment: As for the access date, you need to tell Mendeley about it and you need to tell it to export that field. Apparently this is possible: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269304/35864

Comment: The Mendeley Web Exporter API, which the importer on Overleaf uses, doesn't export the urldate unfortunately. You can export the .bib from Mendeley Desktop instead—that export function does support `urldate`. Unfortunately Overleaf can't change the behavior of the Web Exporter API, as it is maintained by Mendeley—sorry!

Answer (score 2):

thanks for your answers.
For me, it seems like LianTzeLim is right. I couldn't get Mendeley to export it correctly to Overleaf.
So what I do know is to just export my Websites from Mendeley to an own file and remove them from Mendeley. So I'll just have to bibtex files in my project. One direct synchronized from Mendeley and one for my websites that I need to cite.

A bit disappointing that Mendeley can't handle websites correctly. Besides that, it is still a cool tool.