# Editing biblatex with specific format

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apacite

I am try to publish my academic article in this journal https://link.springer.com/journal/10618. In instruction for authors they need reference citation to be like this:

> Bailey N, Kapetanios G, Pesaran M H (2016) Exponent
>   of cross-sectional dependence: estimation and inference. Journal of
>   Applied Econometrics 31: 929-960. https://doi.org/10.1002/jae.2476

I am using biblatex to list my citations. I am get the citation by it is different from what journal want. But this is what I am getting:

> Bailey, Natalia, George Kapetanios, and M Hashem Pesaran (2016). "Exponent
>   of Cross-Sectional Dependence: Estimation and Inference". In: *Journal of
>   Applied Econometrics* 31.6, pp. 929-960. https://doi.org/10.1002/jae.2476

This is my Latex code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[style=authoryear,citetracker=true,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
 \AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{2}}}
 \addbibresource{GoScholarRef.bib}
 \title{\texttt{biblatex}}

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle

  This is a simple text to test citation \parencite{bailey2016exponent} blah bla.

 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

And this is my biblatex file:

```
   @article{bailey2016exponent,
   title={Exponent of Cross-Sectional Dependence: Estimation and Inference},
   author={Bailey, Natalia and Kapetanios, George and Pesaran, M Hashem},
   journal={Journal of Applied Econometrics},
   volume={31},
   number={6},
   pages={929--960},
   year={2016},
   publisher={Wiley Online Library}
   doi = {https://doi.org/10.1002/jae.2476}
   }
```

How can I fix my code to get the exact citation format ?

Comment: The link does not quite work. Have you made sure that they can accept a submission using `biblatex`? Many publishers use workflows that can for technical reasons not involve `biblatex`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864. Do they maybe have a `.bst` file you could use?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, fixed journal link, Springer did provide a bibliography citation style just EndNote format. But they need articles in latex format. @moewe

Comment: Still you should double-check that they can accept `biblatex`. You may have to go back to BibTeX or a fully manual bibliography if not.

Comment: In the instructions on http://www.springer.com/computer/database+management+%26+information+retrieval/journal/10618 there is no comma before the parentheses around the year. Are you sure there must be one?

Comment: they did not mentioned it in the instruction. Unfortunately BibTeX did not helped me  to list the above style. Editing  is bit difficult.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank your for your notice, I fixed the post.

Comment: I have added an answer that implements what you asked for in your example. But please keep in mind that this is a Q&A site and as such questions that are about one particular problem (like "how can I remove the 'in:' before the journal title") are far better suited to this format than 'please create this style for me'. If you split up what you want into several bits, you'll find that much of what you need has been answered on this site already. You can in general not expect people to write a complete style for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will keep in my mind these tips in my future questions. :) @moewe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should double-check with the journal if they can accept `biblatex` submissions. See [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)

Here is a start that implements the example you gave following guidance from http://www.springer.com/computer/database+management+%26+information+retrieval/journal/10618?print_view=true&detailsPage=pltci_2554736

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, citetracker=true, maxcitenames=1, giveninits, terseinits, uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{2}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bailey2016exponent,
  title={Exponent of Cross-Sectional Dependence: Estimation and Inference},
  author={Bailey, Natalia and Kapetanios, George and Pesaran, M Hashem},
  journal={Journal of Applied Econometrics},
  volume={31},
  number={6},
  pages={929--960},
  year={2016},
  doi = {10.1002/jae.2476}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma\space}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
   }
  }
}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\begin{document}
lorem \parencite{bailey2016exponent,knuth:ct:a,sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,westfahl:space,gaonkar:in,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> Bailey N, Kapetanios G, Pesaran MH (2016) Exponent of Cross-Sectional Dependence: Estimation and Inference. Journal of Applied Econometrics 31:929–960. https://doi.org/10.1002/jae.2476.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  Can  split `.bib` to a separate file without using `\usepackage{filecontents}` ? Sorry for keep asking I am new to latex and try to learn bit by bit.

Comment: @medo0070 In general yes. `filecontents` is only used to make the example self-contained. If you want to submit a `.tex` file to your journal it depends - most journals don't want a `.bib` file and need a `.bbl` instead, in which case you can't use `biblatex` as mentioned in the link.