# Can I completely delete BibTex, when moved to biblatex/Biber?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, miktex, biber, texniccenter

I use `TeXnicCenter` and portable `MiKTeX`. Are there some internal dependencies between `MiKTeX` and `BibTeX` or can I safely delete it?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: What's the motivation for this query? Hard disk storage is really, really cheap these days, and deleting all files in question won't free up a lot of space. In short, why bother?

Comment: bibtex isn't very big do you really need to save the space? Many (most) journals will accept bibtex generated bibliographies rather than biblatex ones, so it's wide to keep bibtex even if you use biber in preference

Comment: Hello @Mico and @David Carlisle! Thank you for the comments! The space isn't relevant. It's just interesting for me, how deep is `BibTeX`fixed in my distribution. On the other hand I bother to keep clean my distribution. Well, I agree, maybe it's a bit to much effort.

Comment: Just an advice: don't do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `biblatex` together with Biber, `bibtex` (i.e. `bibtex.exe`) is not needed any more. You could use `biblatex` together with `bibtex` via the `backend=bibtex` option, but that is general not recommended because some functions depend on the Biber backend, and so `bibtex` is considered a 'legacy backend' for `biblatex` now.

*In theory*, then you could delete `bibtex` and your bibliographies would continue to work. There is no hard dependency in MikTeX on the program layer that would require `bibtex` be installed. Unfortunately, though, the package `miktex-bibtex-bin-...` is marked as 'required', so it will always be installed again whenever you run the updater. So you can remove `bibtex`, but it will be re-installed after an update. Of course you can then remove it again.

*But* you don't really save a lot of space if you delete `bibtex`. The `bibtex` binary comes in the package `miktex-bibtex-bin-x64-2.9` on my system and is not even 300 KB (that's right *kilo*bytes) heavy, the standard `.bst` styles and documentation live in the MikTeX package `bibtex` with a bit more than double the size at about 640 KB. So overall you hardly manage to scrape together 1 MB of saves. That's not really an overwhelming result.

On the other hand, if you delete `bibtex`, you can't produce bibliographies with normal `.bst` styles any more. What if someone sends you their document using `plain.bst`? You should also keep in mind that the publishing industry has not (fully) embraced `biblatex` (yet?, at all?). Many journals that accept `.tex` submission do not or can not accept bibliographies produced with `biblatex`. Some journals even offer `.bst` files that you should use. See [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). Even the arXiv, undoubtedly one of the more progressive outlets, makes it much easier to submit BibTeX-generated bibliographies. `biblatex` submissions are possible, mind you, but they require fiddling and going back to outdated releases of `biblatex` and Biber.

So all in all: **Yes in theory**, it is possible to get rid of `bibtex` if you only ever use `biblatex` with Biber, **but it is not worth the hassle** (1MB, one `.exe`, a couple of `.pdf` and `.bst` files saved) and puts limits on how you collaborate with others or how you publish your work. So I close with [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex)'s advice: [don't do it!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430708/can-i-completely-delete-bibtex-when-moved-to-biblatex-biber#comment1079193_430708)