# LaTeX template will not accept .bib files for references

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, overleaf

I'm struggling with the following template:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-nucleic-acids-research-nar-journal/jgwhfndzyykw

My problem is, that in the template, references are added manually. I would like to use a standard .bib file, yet I can't seem to get it right.

It seems overleaf won't let me use biber as backend, and with natbib it returns an error related to chicago.bst file..

Thank you for a working example!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template does not work together with `biblatex`, in fact it loads a modified (!) version of `natbib`. So I strongly advise against trying to get `biblatex` to work and use `natbib` instead. If you are submitting to that journal it is quite unlikely anyway that they can accept `biblatex` submissions, see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)

The following MWE worked fine for me on Overleaf, see https://www.overleaf.com/read/nvzmmrbkmtvd

```
\documentclass[a4,center,fleqn]{NAR}

\copyrightyear{2008}
\pubdate{31 July 2009}
\pubyear{2009}
\jvolume{37}
\jissue{12}

\begin{document}
\title{Article title}
\author{Someone}
\address{Location}

\history{None}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Text.
\end{abstract}

\section{Text}
\cite{wilde,kullback,moore}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

---

That is not to say that there is absolutely no way to get `biblatex` to work with that template ([there is](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pmzmvwxqfpwg)), but you should not go down that route. The particular problem is that the class defines a few commands that `biblatex` needs to define itself and makes the bold move

```
\mathchardef\@m=1500   % adapted value
```

which seems like a *really* bad idea to me, since `biblatex` (and other packages as well) assumes the standard definition of

```
\mathchardef\@m=1000
```

This needs to be fixed so that you end up loading the class with the option `openbib` to avoid `natbib` and

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\undef\bibfont
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\@m=1000
\makeatother
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

to fix its definitions.