# \mathchardef\@m affects punctuation after \cite tag, when using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\@m=1500
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test,.;: for the reference cross link \citet{Glymour16},.;: Also this is end
of the paragraph checking \citet{Glymour16}.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

%%%Content of test.bib%%%

```
% Encoding: UTF-8


@Article{Glymour16,
  author  = {C. Glymour},
  title   = {Responses},
  journal = {Synthese},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {193},
  pages   = {1251--1285},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

The above coding are works fine, but the punctuation (period, command, colon, etc.) after `\cite` commands are disappear. If I remove the tag `\mathchardef\@m=1500` then all are working fine.

Is this correct to remove the tag `\mathchardef\@m=1500`, please suggest....

Also, please advise what is the use of the tag `\mathchardef\@m=1500`...

Comment: Usually `\@m` is defined with `\mathchardef\@m=1000`, so setting it to `1500` is definitely wrong: code that expects it to be a 1000 will behave unexpectedly.

Comment: Er, why are you defining `\@m`?

Comment: @JosephWright It was there in the received TeX file, I didn't include....

Comment: See also the end of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433204/35864.

Comment: It's beyond me why the code you were given sets `\mathchardef\@m=1500`, as there are many places where `\@m` is used as a shorthand for 1000. But whatever the intentions, this is certainly quite dangerous since (as mentioned above) `\@m` is used in many different places and blinding changing values has the potential to change the outcome. The problem with `biblatex` specifically is that it uses `\@m` when it initialises space factor codes for the punctuation tracker. Assigning different values may lead to undesirable punctuation (as observed here).

Comment: redefining `\@m` is like redefining `\def` or `\newcommand` you should not expect latex to work at all after that.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your valuable suggestion....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\@m` is a core latex command that means 1000 if you change that then essentially latex is broken and nothing should be expected to work.

It is used in the definition of `\frenchspacing` so affecting punctuation is not surprising:

```
\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.\@m \sfcode`\?\@m \sfcode`\!\@m
  \sfcode`\:\@m \sfcode`\;\@m \sfcode`\,\@m}
\def\nonfrenchspacing{\sfcode`\.3000\sfcode`\?3000\sfcode`\!3000%
  \sfcode`\:2000\sfcode`\;1500\sfcode`\,1250 }
```

Also in the definition of `\@`

```
\def\@{\spacefactor\@m{}}%
```

so this would no longer force normal spacing (which is 1000 space factor)

It also breaks commands to suppress line spacing, which rely on the "magic" value of -1000pt that TeX uses as a flag in its internal vertical space algorithms.

```
\def\nointerlineskip{\prevdepth-\@m\p@}
\def\offinterlineskip{\baselineskip-\@m\p@
  \lineskip\z@ \lineskiplimit\maxdimen}
```

Comment: Much thanks for your detailed explanation...