# Where are the biblatex files located / biblatex macros defined on a win 7 /miktex system?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-phys

I have to adapt the bibliography layout to comply with the IRC template:

> References should be done using JRR house-style format:
>   For journals - Authors’ names in caps, year in bracket, title, name of journal in italic, volume and issue number in bold, page number.

However, I cannot find this as `biblatex` package. The `phys` style comes close, but needs some editing. I have copied and renamed the `phys.bbx` and -`.cbx` files from the `biblatex-phys.zip`-file, placed them in my document home directory and have them running.

However, I cannot find the basic macro definitions to use them as a template for the changes. They should be in the `biblatex.def` file, but I cannot locate this. In a previous question this was answered for a Linux environment, but `grep` and `kpsewich` are not available in windows. Also, I cannot find the path `/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/` that was suggested as answer in another question. Neither the windows file search option or ultrafinder are of much help.

Comment: Are you sure there is no existing `bst` file to use? Journals often use the old BibTeX way.

Comment: The IRC is member of the ACS, and I used the achemso package before. However, IRC not on the list of supported journals and no-one of the list suits well. The achemso package loads lots of other packages, some of them conflicting with my present set in use. Making some small changes to the phys definitions might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

`kpsewhich` also works on a Windows machine with MikTeX if the MikTeX binary folder is added to the path. So typing

```
kspsewhich biblatex.def
```

in the command line should work if and only if typing

```
pdflatex --help
```

works.

On my machine that file is at

```
C:/Program Files/MikTeX 2.9/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
```

the first bit (`C:/Program Files/MikTeX 2.9/`) was abbreviated to `/texmf/` in the answer you mention. MikTeX installations may have several TEXMF folders and you can find out which folders these are with

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMF
```

or by going to the "Settings" screen of your MikTeX Console and checking the "Directories" tag

[image]

---

Note that not all definitions you may be insterested in live in `biblatex.def`, you may also be interested in

- `standard.bbx`
- `numeric.bbx`
- `numeric-comp.cbx`

---

You may also want to check out the styles of the [`biblatex-chem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) bundle as starting points.

---

Double-check that the journal you want to submit to accepts submissions using `biblatex` (see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)). This might be less of an issue if they want only the compiled PDF, but if they want the `.tex` file you should definitely double check with the editor. In https://academic.oup.com/jrr/pages/Instructions_For_Authors I found

> Please save your manuscript file Word, RTF, format, Figures and Tables can be saved in TIFF, GIF, JPEG, EPS, Excel and PowerPoint.

and https://irc2018.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Fullpaper-Template-Guidelines-IRC2018.pdf insists

> The  abstract  should  be  written  using  Microsoft Word.

Which seems to suggest they don't take LaTeX submissions at all. So I wonder if it is worth the effort.