# Where do I find the bibmacro "title"?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to change how BibLaTeX changes the title of certain entries. I want to do this by modifying the bibmacro for "title". However, I cannot find its default definition anywhere. It is used in `standard.bbx` for example but there does not seem to be any definition. Where can I find the default for this macro?

Comment: Many basic bibmacros are defined in `biblatex.def`. The bibliography drivers and some 'higher-level' bibmacros are defined in `standard.bbx`. The `<style>.bbx` files contain some style specific bibliography modifications. Citation style definitions can be found in `<style>.cbx`. Custom styles usually consist of `<style>.bbx` and `<style>.cbx` as well, but may sometimes rely on additional files.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542043/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456615/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554623/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434768/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lines [2785-2797 of `biblatex.def` (in v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2785-L2797):

```
\newbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}
```