# Command \bibhang already defined with Zotero

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, natbib, templates, zotero

I'm trying to use a Zotero .bib file for the citation backend in this template document setup below but I get the error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:462:
LaTeX Error:
 Command \bibhang already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.462 \newlength{\bibhang}
```

Setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style= authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Zotero.bib}
```

Looking at other posts I believe this is a clash between biblatex and natbib but I can't seem to use the zotero backend without using \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style= authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex} and it won't accept nanbib in the curly brackets.

Is there a way to fix this so that Zotero is recognised using natbib in this way?

Comment: If you use the `mnras` document class you are strongly advised to use `natbib`. It is unlikely that a submission with `biblatex` can be processed properly (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). `biblatex` and `natbib` are incompatible, so you can't load `biblatex`. Zotero is just a reference manager that produces `.bib` files. You should be able to use those `.bib` files (with a few modifications that Zotero should be able to do automatically) with `natbib`.

Comment: Are you planning to submit your paper for MNRAS?

Comment: Okay so I can get rid of the backend comment I wrote in the last paragraph and alter the .bib file to work with the template? Yes I'm using the latest MNRAS template in the above example and intending to publish..do you think using Zotero .bib files are unwise for this?

Comment: No Zotero `.bib` files should be fine as long as the file plays nicely with the style used by the MNRAS template. There a subtle differences in best practices between a `.bib` file prepared for `biblatex` and those for other `.bst` files (note that there is no uniform data model for all BibTeX styles, just a framework). You will probably have to tell Zotero to export for BibTeX and not for `biblatex`. Ideally that should be it.

Comment: Ah okay that's good then, it doesn't look like it's playing well with the document as I have \addbibresource giving an undefined control sequence error, maybe I need to use a packege to handle that command.

Comment: Well, `\addbibresource` is a `biblatex` command (as is `\printbibliography`). You need to use `\bibliography` instead. Follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864 in reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you are submitting your paper for MNRAS

If you are submitting a paper for MNRAS you should not be using `biblatex`. The [`mnras` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/mnras_guide.pdf) mentions two ways to produce a bibliography

1. The manual way with `thebibliography` and
2. the automatic way with BibTeX and `natbib`.

`biblatex` and `natbib` are completely incompatible with each other (see [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) for a short comparison) and it is unlikely that publishers can accept `biblatex` submissions (see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)). So `biblatex` is out of the question.

Of the two ways the automatic way with `natbib` and BibTeX seems to be strongly preferred (p. 7 of the MNRAS documentation)

> This is implemented in LaTeX via the `natbib` package, which in turn is included via the `usenatbib` package option (see section 4), which should be used in all papers.

and

> It is possible to enter references manually using the usual LaTeX commands, but we strongly encourage authors to use BibTeX instead.

So you should dump `biblatex` and use `natbib` as advised instead. That means you need to follow [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) in reverse so that your document looks roughly like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

See also http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/mnras_template.tex

No mention of `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography` can remain (the two are `biblatex` commands) instead you place `\bibliography{<name of bib file without the .bib extension>}` where you want the bibliography to appear.

You may be able to tell Zotero to prepare a `.bib` file for the BibTeX data model instead of `biblatex`. Even though the general structure of the file is the same for the two data models, there are subtle differences between best practices for `biblatex` and best practices for `.bst` files (note that while again the general structure of the `.bib` files should be the same for most `.bst` files there can be differences in the fields and types supported - some old styles don't have a `url` field while many new ones do). For the more common types `@article`, `@book`, `@incollection` it probably does not matter too much, but more fringe types may need special care.

---

### If you are not planning on submitting your paper for MNRAS

If you are not planning to submit your document for the MNRAS you should probably not be using the `mnras` document class. This class is specifically tailored for MNRAS submissions. Publisher classes sometimes have idiosyncrasies and may be hard or impossible to customise (why should they be customisable after all? - they just need to enforce the house style and enable easy processing for the publisher).

Comment: That worked beautifully it was the 

\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

...part that I was missing in trying to get it to work. Thanks so much!