# bibtex + newrefcontext + labelprefix

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm publishing an article to the Software Quality Journal. The bibliography in the article is divided into two groups. One of the groups has a prefix. During article submission it turned out that:

```
Package biblatex Warning: prefixnumbers option to \printbibliography is
no longer supported, use 'labelprefix' option to \newrefcontext.
```

I have checked serveral quesions on 'tex.stackexchange.com' and all of them lead to use `biber` backend. I was able to make it working with `biber`.

But, as far as I know, Software Quality Journal requires `bibtex`...

Is there any way to use `labelprefix` with `bibtex` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Update* Starting from `biblatex` 3.13 a rudimentary version of `labelprefix` is supported with BibTeX. Details can be found at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/852. It is still strongly advised to use Biber, though.

At the moment the BibTeX backend only supports one refcontext for the entire document. In particular that means that you can't have several `labelprefix`es with BibTeX any more. This is one of the things `biblatex` warns you about when you run BibTeX

```
Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
```

I'll have a look whether there is a way to get back at least a bit of `labelprefix` with `backend=bibtex`, but I can't raise your hopes, the whole system is quite a bit more complicated than what simple BibTeX usually allows and BibTeX development is not a priority. (See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/852 - not sure if this will lead anywhere.)

---

As for your issue of getting `labelprefix` to work for a submission to the *Software Quality Journal* I don't think using `biblatex` is going to be a good idea. Most publishers don't accept `biblatex` submissions ([Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)) and I don't think Springer is an exception. I couldn't find a link to a LaTeX template in the Author Guidelines for that journal https://www.springer.com/computer/swe/journal/11219?detailsPage=pltci_2530611, but the normal Springer templates use BibTeX-based bibliography solutions and not `biblatex`. Unless a publisher explicitly states they want `biblatex` I would always assume that they either want their house `.bst` file, a simple `.bst` like `plain` or a manual `thebibliography`. The `biblatex` workflow is very different from the normal bibliography workflow. For the most part the fundamental problems that publishers have with accepting `biblatex` submissions occur regardless whether Biber or BibTeX is used.

The citation style required for the *Software Quality Journal* (a simple author-year system) does not really lend itself to `labelprefix` (which is usually only used with and in standard `biblatex` only supported by `numeric` or `alphabetic` styles), so I doubt that you should use it at all.