# biblatex & biber : \textcite without parenthesis around year

Tags: biblatex, biber, xpatch

I should submit a paper with lots of math, but there is not an available latex class for the journal. However I want to use latex and biblatex (with biber).

The journal specifies, in particular, that: "if more than two authors are present refere them as: 'Bianchi *et al.* 2003' in the text".

I customized a great part of the bibliograhy appareance with the following code (some part refers to the style in the REFERENCE section)

```
\usepackage[backend = biber, style= authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, maxcitenames=2, dashed = true, isbn = false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]{title}{#1}
\addbibresource{article.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% year in the reference section must be without parenthesis
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
 \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
% et al. must be in italic
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
 \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
 \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}
```

However I am not able to remove the parenthesis around the year.
As an example: if I consider the following book:

```
@book{Burroughs_PGIS_2015,
 Author = {Peter A. Burrough and Rachael A. McDonnell and Christopher D. Lloyd},
 Title = {Principles of Geographical Information Systems},
 Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
 Year = {2015},
 ISBN = {0198742843},
 pagetotal = 330
}
```

and the command

```
\textcite{Burroughs_PGIS_2015}
```

I obtain:
Burrough *et al.* (2015) **and not** Burrough *et al.* 2015

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How about a simple `\cite{Burroughs_PGIS_2015}`?

Comment: @gusbrs: YES! Thanks a lot: simplier than I thought.

Comment: Please note that to my knowledge very few journals and publishers accept `biblatex` submissions, since the bibliography workflow for `biblatex` is significantly different from that of BibTeX/`thebibliography`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864. If the journal wants your `.tex` code and not just a PDF you should contact the editor to check if they can accept `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe: you're right! It happens with *elsearticle* class. In my case the publisher accepts the pdf.

Comment: To my knowledge `elsarticle` loads `natbib` and comes with ready-made `.bst` styles. Even though https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions states that many Elsevier journals accept PDF submissions, I would still stick to their advice and use `elsarticle` and BibTeX.

Answer (score 5):

`\textcite` is a citation command designed to be used in the flow of text as a subject of a sentence. Thus it puts a citation label which is enclosed in parentheses after authors' or editors' names. If you'd like to have it (for whatever purpose) without parentheses, you can use the bare `\cite` command which, for the `authoryear` style you are using, will produce a citation alike `\textcite`, but without parentheses.