# Undefined control sequence. \datalist etc

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis and have to use latex for it. In the past I have never used latex in my whole life. Still things running good but I have to use latexdiff with the `--flatten` parameter, which is working great it dumps all the differences between two versions of my thesis into a single file.

On compiling there sadly is a problem with citations, latexdiff converts my literature database .db file into an inline `\datalist`. But this \datalist can't be compiled, because for some strange reason latex doesn't know the commands.

Errors like:

```
Undefined control sequence. \datalist
Undefined control sequence. \entry
Undefined control sequence. \name
```

appearing in the log.

The file is generated automatically by latexdiff, so I don't expect any errors in there, unless there is some bug in latexdiff?

I am using biblatex:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

For managing latex package versions I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and I updated all packages today, so every package is using the newest version.

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: \datalist and the other command are only defined locally when the bbl is read.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer So this is nothing which should be put into a .tex file?

Comment: No, outside of the bbl it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`latexdiff`'s `--flatten` option does not only flatten `\input` and `\include`, it also writes the `.bbl` file into the document. That works well for BibTeX-based bibliographies, where the `.bbl` file contains code that can be typeset directly at the place where `\bibliography` is issued. But it does not work for `biblatex`, where the `.bbl` contains the entry data in a machine-readable, but not typesettable format, and where the file is loaded at a particular point at the beginning of the document and not just where `\bibliography` is placed.

It is possible to include `biblatex`'s `.bbl` into a `.tex` file, but it requires a bit of extra work (see for example [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)) and I would say that it is in general not worth the effort.

Until `latexdiff` becomes aware of `biblatex` and handles it differently, you can do one of the following things

1. Ignore the fact that the `.bbl` bit in the diff output is not compilable. Review it in the source before you compile the diff file and then comment it out.
2. Use `\addbibresource{<filename>.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{<filename>}`. `latexdiff` does not recognise the `biblatex` command and does not try to input the `.bbl` there.

Comment: I am a bit dissappointed that latex has no better way to really view all the diffs between two revsions. Microsoft Word is a lot more powerful in this matter. But thanks for the good solution I hope my professor will accecpt this way.

Comment: @DominikK I rejected the edit removing the `.bib` file extension from `\addbibresource`, because the extension is required with that command (as opposed to `\bibliography` where the file extension must not be given). On some systems it may work without the extension, but that is only accidental and not guaranteed.