# Citation style of Journal of Time Series Analysis

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have been asked to use exactly the following citation style of the Journal of Time Series Analysis (JTSA) while writing a manuscript in LaTeX. I have tried several styles (e.g., cbe, apa, chicago, abbrvnat), but it seems that none of them are exactly what I want. Could anyone kindly tell me what package and style would be in this case?

> > Bravo F. 2002. Blockwise empirical Cressie–Read test statistics for -mixing processes. *Statistics & Probability Letters* **58**: 319–325.
> >
> > Davis RA, Hsing T. 1995. Point process and partial sum convergence for weakly dependent random variables with infinite variance. *The Annals of Probability* **23**: 879–917.
> >
> > Demos A., Kyriakopoulou D. 2018. Finite-Sample Theory and Bias Correction of Maximum Likelihood Estimators in theEGARCH Model. *Journal of Time Series Econometrics* **11**.
> >
> > Ibragimov IA, Linnik Y. 1971. *Independent and Stationary Sequences of Random Variables.* Groningen: Wolters-Noordhoff.

Comment: Hello. This is no question for this site. You should probably head over to academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please bug your tutors and professors until they tell you which citation style it is, then you can go to the [CSL repository](https://citationstyles.org/authors/) and see if you can find it there. I thought there was a site where you could put in the style you wanted and it would try to find to which style it corresponds, but I can't find the site anymore.

Comment: @thymaro I don't see why this is off topic here, provided the OP wants to implement it in LaTeX. The question is too vague to be answered, since a single reference example massively underdetermines what the style might require. But as it stands this is a very standard Author/Year style with a bolded volume number. Quite simple to do with `biblatex`.  And CSL repos aren't much help for LaTeX, since there aren't packages that implement them in LaTeX.

Comment: @shanks Welcome to the TeX.se. Unfortunately you haven't really provided enough information for us to answer your question. Bibliography styles are more complex than the format of an article entry. We can provide a way to format articles as you describe, but that won't solve all the other possible entry types. So you minimally need a better description of the actual style requirements. Is this for a particular journal? Do they have LaTeX support in the form of a `.bst` file for the journal specifically?

Comment: Thanks, @AlanMunn! I have seen that the Journal of Time Series Analysis uses the style I am asking for.

Comment: Close voters please read the comments before closing.  This is absolutely *not* off topic.

Comment: @AlanMunn not anymore, it isn't. When I first commented on this, JTSA had not been added, and this is crucial information, as I am aware you know ;) now, there are even more examples, which makes the lives of potential answerers easier

Comment: @AlanMunn hmm, yes, I see the issue with CSL repo. Unfortunately, LaTeX doesn't make use of it (I understand this is probably beyond the scope of the L3 team atm and might also be too much for any one person to implement, I don't know how these things work). What I wanted to help with, is a starting point for OP to get the chance to provide us with the name of the CS, so a solution can be found in LaTeX.

Comment: @thymaro sorry but even without the missing information the question was clearly on topic. And we try not to close unclear questions immediately but instead leave comments asking for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The style examples given are only from journal articles, which severely underdetermines the style, but since that's the only information the journal webpage gives, we'll go with it. Maybe nobody cites other sources. :)

This is fairly simple to do with `biblatex`.  I'm using the extended styles from the `biblatex-ext` styles to make some of the modifications simpler.  As moewe notes in the comments, `biblatex` solutions are often not usable for journal submission using LaTeX (i.e., if the journal accepts TeX source documents, then a `biblatex` solution may cause problems.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp,
    articlein=false,
    uniquename=init,
    giveninits=true,
    terseinits=true,
    ]{biblatex}

% make volume bold
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
% remove parentheses from year in bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
% remove quotes and pp. from article formatting
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}
% strict last-first name order
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
% colon between volume and pages
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\addnbspace}
% period at the end of the last name
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod\space}
% no 'and' in name lists in the bibliography
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}[bib]{multinamedelim}
% no issue number
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{number}}{}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
 \textcite{bertram}

 \textcite{herrmann}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: :D I can identify myself with the second bib entry

Comment: It should be noted that a publisher might not be able to accept a submission using `biblatex`. Firstly, their system might be too old for some of the features that you need (`biblatex-ext` is relatively new and is for example not available on Overleaf or the arXiv, I suspect many publishers have similarly old systems). Secondly, even if their system has the features you need, there could still be other version incompatibilities if the publisher expects the `.bbl` instead of the `.bib` file. The `.bbl` file is tightly coupled to the particular `biblatex`/Biber version that produced it. ...

Comment: ... Thirdly, the publisher's workflow might rely on the 'ready-to-typeset' `.bbl` files produced by BibTeX instead of the 'pre-digested raw data' `.bbl` file for `biblatex`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/14679892/homepage/forauthors.html says that the *Journal of Time Series Analysis* uses *ScholarOne Manuscripts*. The checklist in ScholarOne's [Author LaTex File Upload Guide](http://mchelp.manuscriptcentral.com/gethelpnow/tutorials/authorlatexfileupload.pdf) contains the item *Files were generated using pdfTeX Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13, TeXLive 2012 or earlier versions.* That doesn't bode well for `biblatex` (version 2.0 of `biblatex` was released after the 2012 freeze, we're at v3.12 now).

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I've updated the code to reflect your comments.