# biblatex/bibtex: how to match the Palgrave communication bibliographic style?

Tags: bibtex

I need to build a bibliographic style for Nature Palgrave Communication.
The bibliographic style is not completely defined, I only have access to their guidelines that are made out of examples:
https://www.nature.com/palcomms/for-authors/submission-guidelines#references
After multiple emails with the editors I understood that they will not help in providing more clear rules nor in providing a LaTeX template.

Using `natbib` seems to be not enough for this case (but I might be wrong).

I tried `latex makebst` but I got stuck on some questions that were very hard to interpret.

`biblatex` seems to be the ideal solution (modern and flexible), but I have been unable to match the desired output.
Some things are weird in the guidelines, for example the page numbers are prepended by pp in some cases and in others they aren't.

Any help towards the direction of matching this style would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's hard to say, without a code, but what they want looks very much like one of the `author-year` styles. I'd suggest to use this style first, and later, if necessary to adjust the style to the exact requirements. Biblatex is easier to customise than bibtex, and you can look at the examples that come with documentation.

Comment: Please note that many publishers can't deal with `biblatex` submissions as it requires a completely different workflow than BibTeX/`thebibliography` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). Note that questions asking to write a complete style (or large parts of a style) are not a great fit for this site: ideally a question should revolve around one specific issue of general interest.

Comment: Yes indeed I checked and biblatex would not be feasible to them. I will try again with latex makebst

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, preparing my references for palcomm. How did you solve the problem in the end? I'm familiar enough with LaTeX/BibTex/Biblatex, but this is causing me a real headache. Thanks for any hint you could give me!

Comment: This works https://github.com/AlessandroChecco/palcomms_bib

Answer (score 0):

This repository is good enough for palcomms https://github.com/AlessandroChecco/palcomms_bib