# Style file incompatible with package biblatex

Tags: biblatex, natbib, templates

I need to use [the NeurIPS template](https://neurips.cc/Conferences/2019/PaperInformation/StyleFiles). However, with the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[final]{neurips_2019}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee]{biblatex}

\title{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

(the .sty file is in the same path as the .tex file) I get:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.
```

How can I get around this error?

Comment: Neurips seems to internally load natbib which can't be used in combination with biblatex. Therefore, drop biblatex and stick with the functionalities of natbib.

Comment: @leandriis can you be more precise on your suggestion? When I uncommented `\usepackage{biblatex}` I had many new errors arising and even the pdf in overleaf failed to display. What do you want us to do?

Comment: did you try `\usepackage[nonatbib, preprint]{neurips_2021}`? I think that solved my problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`neurips_2019.sty` loads the citation/bibliography package `natbib`. `natbib` is incompatible with `biblatex` since `biblatex` reimplements LaTeX's citation features completely. That's why you get the error

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.
```

Since the package you need to use for submission loads `natbib`, the obvious way to resolve this issue is not to load `biblatex`. The accompanying file https://media.neurips.cc/Conferences/NeurIPS2019/Styles/neurips_2019.tex mentions that the exact citation style does not matter, so you could go with something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[final]{neurips_2019}

\title{Lorem}
\author{A. Uthor}

\begin{document}
\cite{blub}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

which is based on standard `natbib` styles.

Comment: `% to avoid loading the natbib package, add option nonatbib:
%     \usepackage[nonatbib]{neurips_2019}` I saw it just now.

Comment: @Vorac Even if it is possible not to load `natbib` with the style file (and it thus becomes possible to load `biblatex`) I would recommend against using `biblatex` in  a submission unless the publisher explicitly allows `biblatex`. Since `biblatex` uses a completely different implementation of citations and bibliography than, `thebibliography`, classical BibTeX and `natbib`, publishers may not be able to deal with `biblatex` as expected. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864. ...

Comment: ... It is usually safer to stick with `natbib`, especially if there is no need for advanced `biblatex` features or customisability.

Comment: Can someone clarify what natbib is and where it is loaded? I'm getting the original error in this post from the ICML template, but I don't see where natbib is loaded

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer `natbib` is a LaTeX package that implements some nice features for bibliographies and citations. You can learn more about it in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. In the example here the package was loaded by `neurips_2019.sty`. I don't know your template, so I can't tell you exactly where `natbib` is loaded. But if your template loads `natbib` you probably should be using `natbib` and not `biblatex` (the two are incompatible and if the publisher prefers `natbib` they probably have a reason for that).

Comment: now when I do `\usepackage[nonatbib]{neurips_2021}` I get the issue that the authors appears as anonymous...I don't want that! I want normal authors displayed in the paper. Any ideas?

Comment: Somehow for the problem was solved by doing `\usepackage[nonatbib, preprint]{neurips_2021}`

Answer (score 0):

For me using `\usepackage[nonatbib, preprint]{neurips_2021}` and removing `\usepackage{biblatex}` worked.

e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

% if you need to pass options to natbib, use, e.g.:
%     \PassOptionsToPackage{numbers, compress}{natbib}
% before loading neurips_2021

% ready for submission
% \usepackage{neurips_2021}

% to compile a preprint version, e.g., for submission to arXiv, add add the
% [preprint] option:
% \usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2021}

% to compile a camera-ready version, add the [final] option, e.g.:
% \usepackage[final]{neurips_2021}
% \usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2021}

% to avoid loading the natbib package, add option nonatbib:
% \usepackage[nonatbib]{neurips_2021}
\usepackage[nonatbib, preprint]{neurips_2021}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colors

\newcommand{\yx}[1]{{\small\color{blue}{\bf yx: #1}}}
\newcommand{\sk}[1]{{\small\color{red}{\bf sk: #1}}}
\newcommand{\bm}[1]{{\small\color{green}{\bf bm: #1}}}

%% my imports

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{egbib.bib}
...
```