# References don't work before the last section

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I am trying to write a paper and after hours of figuring out how to properly work with Biber. Everythink was working well until i moved to the next section. The references disappeared and all that was left was bunch of zeros as seen in the photos.  [image: Section One]  in the next section references are working well but only in that section not the previous one. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{Measuring ...}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} G}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{S} \\
\textit{I}\\
Th \\
.edu.gr}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} S}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Science and Technology} \\
\textit{I}\\
Th \\
ihu.edu.gr}}


\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This document is a model and instructions for latex
This and the IEEEtran.cls file define the components of your paper [title, text, heads, etc.]. *CRITICAL: Do Not Use Symbols, Special Characters, Footnotes, 
or Math in Paper Title or Abstract.

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
component, formatting, style, styling, insert
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Epileptic...}
The EEG ... intervals and seizure intervals~\cite{alotaiby}. 
Therefore pattern recognition algorithms such as $k$-Nearest Neighbour ($k$-NN) or machine learning Neural Networks are necessary to analyse such data.\cite{liu} 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{fig1.png}
\caption{An EEG signal with containing a seizure~\cite{alotaiby}}
\end{figure}  


\subsection{Data}
Our dataset ...an epileptic seizure~\cite{andrze}. Data available at:~\url{https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Epileptic+Seizure+Recognition}   

\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Rescaling}
In Machine learning.. [-1,1] with the general form been~\cite{aksoy_resc}:

\begin{align}
x' = \frac{x-min(x)}{max(x)-min(x)}\
\end{align}  

where $x$ is the original value and $x'$ the normalized one.

\subsection{$k$-Nearest Neighbors}
The $k$-nearest neighbors algorithm ($k$-NN) is a non-parametric method used for classification and regression~\cite{altman_knn}. In our problem we have a classification problem. For classification the output of the k-NN is a class membership , in our study is whether we have an epileptic seizure or not. Our object will be classified by the plurality vote of the neighbours with the subject of been epileptic seizure or not, among $k$ nearest neighbours. 

The $k$-NN algorithm is one of the simplest across other machine learning algorithms. In the training phase the algorithm only of storing the class labes and feature vectors of the training sample~\cite{coomans_knn}. Then the user-defined $k$ and a unlabelled vector is classified with the labels that classify the $k$ nearest training sample points. The metric that we used for measuring the distance between the neighbours is the Euclidean distance~\cite{phyu_knn}     


\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have `refsection=section` in your `biblatex` loading options. Essentially that means that each `\section` has a bibliography of its own. If you want only one global bibliography, remove `refsection=section` and compile again. (I should add that `IEEEtran` is a document class for submissions to IEEE journals and proceedings that comes with its own BibTeX `.bst` styles. If you want to submit to the IEEE you should use their BibTeX styles and not `biblatex`. If you don't want to submit to the IEEE a standard class might be a better choice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour can be reproduced in the slightly smaller MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric,
  defernumbers=true, refsection=section]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
Lorem~\cite{nussbaum}

\section{Ipsum}
Ipsum~\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [0]//Ipsum [1]//(Bibliography only contains <code>sigfridsson</code>)]

It is caused by the option

```
refsection=section,
```

and is exacerbated (luckily, otherwise you might have never realised there is an issue) by `defernumbers=true,`.

`refsection=section,` tells `biblatex` to start a new `refsection` for each `\section` (or `\section*`) command in your document. `refsection`s are designed to produce several completely independent bibliographies in your document. A `\printbibliography` is always local to the current `refsection` and will ignore citations from other `refsection`s.

In the example, the `\printbibliography` belongs to the second `\section` (`\section{Ipsum}` in my example, `\section{Methodology}` in the example from the question) and will only pick up citations from there.
The citations from the first section are left hanging without a `\printbibliography` (note how the `nussbaum` reference does not appear in any bibliography). Due to the `defernumbers=true,` the number is only assigned to the citations when they first appear in a `\printbibliography`. The entries from the first section never appear in any `\printbibliography` and thus all get the dummy value "[0]".

I assume you want a global bibliography for your document, so the solution is to remove the option

```
refsection=section,
```

If you only have a single bibliography list, you can additionally remove the option

```
defernumbers=true,
```

---

I should add that `IEEEtran` is a document class for submissions to IEEE journals and proceedings that comes with [its own BibTeX `.bst` styles](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex). If you want to submit to the IEEE, you should use their BibTeX styles and not `biblatex` (t is unlikely that the IEEE  can and will accept `biblatex` submissions since they require a different workflow: [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)). If you don't want to submit to the IEEE, a standard class might be a better choice than `IEEEtran`.