# Dataset reference style in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

The journal I am submitting to wants datasets to be listed in the reference as

> [dataset] Authors; Year; Dataset title; Data repository or archive; Version (if any); Persistent identifier (e.g. DOI),

where "[dataset]" at the beginning is literal.  The type of other references (articles, books, etc) does not need to be prefixed in this way.

`biblatex` has a `@dataset` entry type, and I have gotten close to the target using this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@dataset{test,
  author = {The Author},
  title = {Very Big and Important Dataset},
  year = {2020},
  doi = {XX.XXXX/XXX.XXXX.XXXXXXXX},
  publisher = {Dryad}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Text \parencite{test}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks pretty good, but how can I get the `[dataset]` added to the beginning?

Comment: Before you go down the rabbit hole of a `biblatex` solution, double check with the journal that they can accept `biblatex` submissions. `biblatex` requires a different workflow than classical BibTeX or `thebibliography` and may not be supported by all publishers. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864

Comment: Should the "[dataset]" you want to add to the beginning alter the sorting? Should your example entry be sorted under "A" for author or under "d" for "dataset"? (I would find it quite unfortunate to start off the entry with something that has no influence on sorting.)

Comment: Good point that they may not accept it anyway; I should check.

Comment: My understanding is that it should not influence the sorting.  It is not included in the in-line citations, so it would be difficult to find the appropriate reference for (Author, 2020) if it was alphabetized under D for Dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most `biblatex` styles you can hook into the beginning of the entry by redefining the bibmacro `begentry`. Then it's just a matter of checking the entry type and printing a suitable string.

The original definition of `begentry` can be found in `apa.bbx` ([ll. 673-674](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/b9ed20f69894145aa32c6781f2fe6530b50784e7/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/bbx/apa.bbx#L673-L674)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{dataset}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  dataset = {dataset},
}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \ifkeyword{meta}{\textsuperscript{*}}{}%
  \ifentrytype{dataset}
    {\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{dataset}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@dataset{test,
  author    = {The Author},
  title     = {Very Big and Important Dataset},
  year      = {2020},
  doi       = {XX.XXXX/XXX.XXXX.XXXXXXXX},
  publisher = {Dryad},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Text \autocite{test}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Dataset] Author, T. (2020). Very big and important dataset. Dryad. https://doi.org/XX.XXXX/XXX.XXXX.XXXXXXXX]

I don't think this kind of markup is particularly useful. Most readers who care can probably tell that the entry is a data set fairly quickly anyway. What I find most problematic about this is that the "[dataset]" visually shields the "Author 2020" in the bibliography, but "Author 2020" is relevant for sorting.