# Dataset reference style in BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I am writing a Journal Paper which wants datasets to be listed in the reference as

[dataset] Authors; Year; Dataset title; Data repository or archive; Version (if any); Persistent identifier (e.g. DOI),

where "[dataset]" at the beginning is literal. The type of other references (articles, books, etc) does not need to be prefixed in this way. I have already seen the solution given for it at the following link

[Dataset reference style in BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532449/dataset-reference-style-in-biblatex)

But unable to understand. Please help me with working code.
 My code is available at

https://www.overleaf.com/1777417966pvxjpytpthkj

and my bibliography file name is `mybibfile.bib` with following contents

```
@article{gross2010multi,
  title={Multi-pie},
  author={Gross, Ralph and Matthews, Iain and Cohn, Jeffrey and Kanade, Takeo and Baker, Simon},
  journal={Image and Vision Computing},
  volume={28(5)},
  number={5},
  pages={807--813},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

my LaTex code is using bibtex. Please giive your suggestion. My LaTex code is

````````
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}
\biboptions{authoryear}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{xyz}
\author{abc}
\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\address{Research Scholar,}
\ead{abc@gmail.com} 
\begin{abstract}
jhjasvhjsh hjshjhjvhjsvh jjkjbkjbkjk jvkjvzjvkjvkj 
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
abc \sep xyz. 
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
Text-only mode can also be used for someone who is blind or hard of seeing and only needs the text read to them \citep{gross2010multi}.
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```````
````````

Comment: The title of the question mentions BibTeX, but the question is tagged `biblatex`. Do you use BibTeX or `biblatex`? If you are submitting your paper to a journal chances are they won't accept `biblatex` submissions, but if you are lucky the provide a BibTeX bibliography style for you to use.

Comment: Note that the code in the answer to the question you mention (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532449/35864) is working and produces exactly the output shown in the image with an up-to-date system. It may not be useful to you, though, if you use BibTeX and not `biblatex`.

Comment: It would be ideal if you could show us a short example document of how you produce your bibliography and citations at the moment. That helps us understand whether you use BibTeX or `biblatex` and also tells us what style you use. A solution will depend crucially on all of these variables. We will probably not be able to help you with code that "just works" unless we know exactly how you produce your bibliography.

Comment: Please do not share your code only on Overleaf: Make it into a truly minimal example document with only the relevant code and post it here directly. Overleaf links may go stale after a while or may get changed. They sometimes also require registration. As far as I can see, the code you posted does not use  `biblatex` at all, so I'm retagging your question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to edit the bibliography style to get it to work. Here is what I did:

Edit: In this case, I used the `model5-names.bst` from Elsevier journals. (I believe it's the one for APA citations, if I am not mistaken).

First I created a bbl function to print "[Dataset]". You can just copy an existing one and edit it, for me this worked:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.datasetbracket}
{ "[Dataset]" }
```

Secondly, I checked the type of reference I had for my data-sets. In this case, it was an `article`.

I looked for the block called `FUNCTION{article}`, duplicated it, and renamed it to `datasetype`. Finally, I added my `bbl.datasetbracket` function to it.

```
FUNCTION {datasetype}
{ "%Type = Article" write$
  output.bibitem
  bbl.datasetbracket
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      ", " *
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  print.url output
  print.doi output
  print.eprint output
  print.pubmed output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Now I just call the reference on my bib file as `@datasetype{blabla, ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by *user2434449*, here is a slightly smaller version which worked better for me.
It avoided the BibTex error: "the literal stack isn't empty".

1. There is no need to create a `FUNCTION {bbl.datasetbracket}`, just output the text in `FUNCTION {datasetype}` directly, followed by `write$`.
2. I suggest to use `FUNCTION {misc}` instead of `FUNCTION{article}` as a starting one to clone, that avoids warnings about missing journal.
3. Beware that Overleaf seems to cache Bibtex results, I had to comment/uncomment the whole `\bibliographystyle` command, and Recompile in-between to make changes from the `.bst`-file appear.

Thus, my recipe is as follows:

1. Open the appropriate `.bst`-file, I use the Harvard-style `\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}` for the *Elsevier Medical Image Analysis* journal.
2. Go to the function `FUNCTION {misc}` and copy the block to a new function `FUNCTION {datasettype}` (I avoid the name `dataset` to not potentially clash with existing stuff in BibLatex.)
3. Add `"[dataset] " write$` after the first `output.bibitem`, see example below.
4. Use `@datasettype{...}` in your `.bib`-file.
5. And **yes**, I definitely think that Elsevier needs to update their templates to address and document this issue properly!

```
FUNCTION {datasettype}
{ "%Type = Dataset" write$
  output.bibitem
  "[dataset] " write$ 
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title output
  new.block
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  new.block
  print.url output
  print.doi output
  print.eprint output
  print.pubmed output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```