# Add [dataset] identifier before the reference to identify it as a data reference in Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf, els-cas

I'm writing a journal paper which requires datasets to be listed in the format of :

"[dataset] [6] M. Oguro, S. Imahiro, S. Saito, T. Nakashizuka, Mortality data for Japanese oak wilt disease and surrounding forest compositions, Mendeley Data, v1, 2015. https:// xwj98nb39r.1."

How to add [dataset] before the reference number to identify it as a data reference.

i.e. [dataset] followed by [reference number]

like.....[dataset] [6]

I have followed this link and tried to work with suggested solution [Dataset reference style in BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541520/dataset-reference-style-in-bibtex) but I can only manage to add [dataset] identifier after the reference number.

Comment: Someone should add the tag #data in order to get Splunk :) :) ;)