# How can I reproduce a bibliography style with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I have wasted several hours and tried lots of things but still can't achieve the perfect match which the editor of a journal wants. Here is a picture of the style required:[image: references listed in journal]

So far I can manage using this MWE some of the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbib=true,%
            backref=true,%
            backend=biber,%
            style=ext-authoryear,%
            articlein=false,%
            giveninits=true,%
            maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,%
            uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addnbspace No. #1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    andothers = {\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
}
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{,}

%\addbibresource{../Xbib.bib}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib1.bib}
%
@Article{bru30,
  author       = {Jean-Louis Bertrand and Xavier Brusset},
  title        = {Managing the financial consequences of weather variability},
  journal      = {Journal of Asset Management},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Asset Management},
  year         = {2018},
  date         = {2018-07-16},
  volume       = {19},
  issue        = {5},
  pages        = {301-315},
  doi          = {10.1057/s41260-018-0083-x},
  file         = {:Managing the financial consequences of weather variability_JAM.pdf:PDF},
  groups       = {Meteo},
  owner        = {XB},
}

@Article{laz1,
  author    = {J. K. Lazo and M. Lawson and P. H. Larsen and D. M. Waidmann},
  title     = {U.{S}. economic sensitivity to weather variability},
  journal   = {Bulletin of American Meteorological Society},
  year      = {2011},
  volume    = {92},
  pages     = {709-720},
  groups    = {Meteo},
  owner     = {XB},
  timestamp = {2013.11.12},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This document must be compiled after having defined the bibtex command to  \texttt{biber.exe}.

Minimum working example where using \parencite{bru30}. When there are various authors to a paper: \parencite{laz1}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the output, several things are not correct. The given names' initials should always follow the family name, there shouldn't be a date with the year of the publication, the full stop after the year should be a comma, the title of the article should be between inverted commas, the separator between the title and the journal should be a comma. The doi should be preceded by "available at:"
Which style is that? How can I imitate it?
Thank you.

Comment: Please note that it is usually better to ask about **one thing** (that is generally applicable or of general interest) instead of several (related, no doubt) things, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. Though there are ample examples to the contrary on this site I think that questions that come down to: "how can I reproduce this style" are too broad for this site. Your question would benefit from being split up into separate one-issue-questions.

Comment: Note that the two entries shown in the screenshot are probably both `@inproceedings` entries, but your MWE contains `@artcle` entries, so it is not entirely clear to me what is wanted here.

Comment: For the name order you'll probably want `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`. For the commas `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}` seems to be best (you won't need `\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{,}` then; in any case don't ever use a naked `,` when you defined punctuation in `biblatex`, use `\addcomma`).

Comment: One last thing for now, since you mention the editor of a journal: Be warned that not all publishers can accept `biblatex`. `biblatex` requires a different workflow from classic BibTeX, which might be a problem for publishers. Usually journals that accept LaTeX submissions have some kind of author guidelines and sometimes even LaTeX templates that tell you which packages you should use and how you should generate the bibliography. I would not try to use `biblatex` unless specifically instructed to do so. Check with the editor before you go ahead. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12179/

Comment: I thank you for your comments. In particular, I'll check with the publisher about using biblatex. I'll try the hints you suggest. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, here is the work-around that I tried to get the best possible looking imitation for the reference style in the journal I am aiming to submit to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbib=true,%
            backref=true,%
            backend=biber,%
            style=ext-authoryear,%
            articlein=false,%
            giveninits=true,%
            maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,%
            uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\addnbspace Vol. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{issue}{\addnbspace No. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addnbspace No. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journal}{ #1\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    andothers = {\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
%\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{,}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma}
%\renewcommand{\postvolpunct}{\addcomma} % for biblatex-chicago only

\addbibresource{myXbib.bib}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myXbib.bib}

@Article{bru30,
  author       = {Jean-Louis Bertrand and Xavier Brusset},
  title        = {Managing the financial consequences of weather variability},
  journal      = {Journal of Asset Management},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Asset Management},
  year         = {2018},
  date         = {},
  volume       = {19},
  issue        = {5},
  pages        = {301-315},
  doi          = {10.1057/s41260-018-0083-x},
  file         = {:Managing the financial consequences of weather variability_JAM.pdf:PDF},
  groups       = {Meteo},
  owner        = {XB},
}

@Article{laz1,
  author    = {J. K. Lazo and M. Lawson and P. H. Larsen and D. M. Waidmann},
  title     = {U.{S}. economic sensitivity to weather variability},
  journal   = {Bulletin of American Meteorological Society},
  year      = {2011},
  volume    = {92},
  pages     = {709-720},
  groups    = {Meteo},
  owner     = {XB},
  timestamp = {2013.11.12},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article ]{issue}
\DeclareFieldFormat{no}{\bibsstring{number}~#1}
This document must be compiled after having defined the bibtex command to  \texttt{biber.exe}.

Minimum working example where using \parencite{bru30}. When there are various authors to a paper: \parencite{laz1}.
K\oe nig is the author of various books and articles, \parencite[see][ for an example]{koe1}, \cite{boiral_2006}.

Some citation alternative uses: \citeauthor{koe1} says in \citeyear{koe1}, this is what is expected. Does foot citation possibility work \footcite{simon_1996}?

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Note how I had to remove the brackets around the issue number by redefining the way an issue number is listed:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{no}{\bibsstring{number}~#1}
```

I hope this helps somone. It took me various days to obtain this result.