# Package biblatex Error: Patching \addtocontents failed

Tags: biblatex, errors

This is a bit urgent. I'm getting an error on my file (it complies on Overleaf but not on pdflatex), and I cannot figure out how to fix this. I've checked the documentation, and a lot of other stack overflow questions, but I can't figure this out.

Any suggestions?

Full error:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Patching \addtocontents failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I don't actually use addtocontents anywhere, and I'm getting this error at
\begin(document).

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{bbold}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=vancouver, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references2.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}

...


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: No one will be able to help you unless you provide your source file that is causing the trouble.  Try to reduce it to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/21053) that you can post as part of the question.

Comment: And where exactly is that document class available?

Comment: The document class is available in an attached CLS file, which I cannot edit (it's provided by the publisher https://www.iospress.nl/service/authors/latex-and-word-tools-for-book-authors/ )

Comment: Is this a problem with the CLS file, rather than my code? That's what I have been able to conclude, at least.

Comment: The example `.tex` file that comes in the `.zip` file you point to has its bibliography generated with manual `thebibliography`. `thebibliography` is completely incompatible with `biblatex` and I find no mention of `biblatex` anywhere in the documentation. The workflow of some (many/most) publishers is incompatible with `biblatex`. My usual advice is to avoid `biblatex` in submissions to publishers/journals unless they explicitly ask you to use it. (See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864.)

Answer (score 1):

For strange reasons, the class does

```
\long\def\addtocontents#1#2{}
```

which is pretty useless because it doesn't even define `\tableofcontents` and alike commands so it's not a problem having `\addtocontents` do something.

You can avoid the error by replacing `\addtocontents` with its kernel meaning and do what the class wants later on (even if useless).

I'd avoid calling `titlesec` because the submission might be rejected for not being compliant.

```
\let\latexaddtocontents\addtocontents
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}
\let\addtocontents\latexaddtocontents

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\AtBeginDocument{\let\addtocontents\@gobbletwo\setcounter{author}{0}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{bbold}

\usepackage{multirow}

%\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=vancouver, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references2.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

abc

\end{document}
```

I also added `\setcounter{author}{0}` because the class defines the counter for the purpose of `\maketitle`, but then it is needed by `biblatex` and in the body the value should start at zero as `biblatex` expects.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!

Comment: "I'd avoid calling titlesec because the submission might be rejected for not being compliant."
How likely is that, do you think? Otherwise there's a half a page worth of content I need to extract from somewhere in my paper.

Comment: @D.Geek If I were the copy editor, I'd immediately strip off that line and, if the paper exceeds the page limit, at least send it back for editing.

Comment: Thanks, that saved me a lot of pain I imagine.

Comment: Additionally, would you happen to know why sometimes the compiler simply refuses to recognise the bib file and its codes?

Comment: @D.Geek Sorry, no idea. I added a test bib file and the result is as expected.