# How can I access a journal's bibliography format and use it myself?

Tags: biblatex

I have my `.bib` file ready and am using `biblatex`. I'm confronted with these bibliography examples:

> For journals: Parry, M. (1990) The potential impact on agriculture of the greenhouse effect. Land Use Policy 7, 109-123.
> Oguro, M., Imahiro, S., Saito, S., Nakashizuka, T., 2015. Mortality data for Japanese oak wilt disease and surrounding forest compositions. Mendeley Data, v1. http://dx.doi.org/10.17632/xwj98nb39r.1.

> For books: El-Hinnawi, E. and Hashmi, M. H. (1987) The State of the Environment. Butterworths, Kent.

Note there are no italics anywhere. I can't recognize the style (I looked at a dozen [here](https://www.scribbr.com/citing-sources/citation-styles/) to no avail, couldn't find any other lists of styles). The journal is called [Global Environmental Change](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/global-environmental-change/0959-3780/guide-for-authors), if that helps. Is there a way I can avoid re-implementing their bibliography and citation format? I am not experienced with LaTeX. How do academics normally make sure their styles conform with a particular journal's style? Surely they don't all re-implement the bibliography and citation styles from scratch?

Comment: If a journal accepts tex source they normally provide the bibtex style. If they do not accept tex source it doesn't matter much what style you use as the journal will probably  rekey the entire article anyway in their own system (quite likely not tex at all)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Do potential authors get bonus points for submitting it in the proper style the first time? Or do they not care at all?

Comment: It really depends on the journal. Some journals literally print the supplied file and have it retyped so they could not care less what fonts or styles you use so long as it is readable.  Some use the actual tex source in production, and some are in between.

Comment: I had a quick look at the author notes for that  journal, as far as I can see they explicitly say the submission doesn't need to be formatted like the journal, only after acceptance will you need to upload it into their online editing system (at which point tex styling is presumably not relevant)

Comment: but you should ask the journal not me:-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer; this really depends on the journal.

Some journals that accept LaTeX submissions have detailed author guidelines outlining how you should generate your references. Some even come with a LaTeX template that includes a BibTeX (`.bst`) file for you to use. If the submission guidelines mention anything explicitly, obviously that's what you should be using.

Depending on the publishing workflow, submission of `.tex` instead of PDF files might be more of a courtesy to authors, because the real publication process may not involve LaTeX at all or only in preliminary stages. In this case, the references will probably be extracted properly regardless of the exact formatting you apply when you submit your article as long as it is consistent and the information complete.

For publishers that postprocess submitted `.tex` source it may be a problem if you do "non-standard" things in your document. Unless there are specific guidelines to the contrary it is probably better to stay on the safe side by not using fancy packages or doing fancy stuff. For bibliographies it is worth keeping in mind that `biblatex` requires a completely different workflow than classical BibTeX. That's why I would usually not use `biblatex` for journal submissions, even if there is no explicit information about the bibliography workflow. See also [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). But if the publisher never gets to see the `.tex` source and only ever works with a submitted PDF that is less of an issue.

As [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) [mentions in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577204/how-can-i-access-a-journals-bibliography-format-and-use-it-myself#comment1453087_577204) the [author guidelines for *Global Environmental Change* say](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/global-environmental-change/0959-3780/guide-for-authors#txt20102)

> **References**
>
> There are no strict requirements on reference formatting at submission.
> References can be in any style or format as long as the style is consistent.
> Where applicable, author(s) name(s), journal title/book title,
> chapter title/article title, year of publication, volume number/book chapter
> and the article number or pagination must be present.
> Use of DOI is highly encouraged.
> The reference style used by the journal will be applied
> to the accepted article by Elsevier at the proof stage.
> Note that missing data will be highlighted at proof stage for the author to correct.

So you need not worry at all about the exact formatting of your references as long as the output is complete and consistent (the latter of which is one of the main points of using bibliography styles in the LaTeX world, so you should be good as long as your input – i.e. your `.bib` file – is good).

Later on we find

> **Submission**
>
> Our online submission system guides you stepwise through the process
> of entering your article details and uploading your files.
> The system converts your article files to a single PDF file
> used in the peer-review process.
> Editable files (e.g., Word, LaTeX) are required
> to typeset your article for final publication.

which suggests the publisher may want to process the `.tex` source directly, so I would advise using only "standard methods" to generate the bibliography. I'd definitely not go for `biblatex` here, but I may be tempted to use a BibTeX style that is slightly more modern than `plain` (which was written before DOIs were a thing) – maybe something from `natbib`.

Elsevier has several publisher classes (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle and https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates) also including bibliography styles, that you could check out. Though a simple `\documentclass{article}` will probably do the job just as well.

**If in doubt, don't listen to random people on the internet: Get in touch with the journal editors and ask them.**