# How to edit the Bibliography style using BibLatex and a .bib exterior file, in Overleaf?

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I really don't know how to edit the style.

I was following this post [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles?noredirect=1&lq=1) which has the concerns that I have but got stock in its answer in the

> I recommend to use the configuration file biblatex.cfg. This file, if available, is read by biblatex immediately after a style has been loaded. The (empty) original is located at /tex/latex/biblatex in your TeX distribution directory; put a copy in the analogous location of your local TEXMF tree (and update your file database) and fill it with the redefinitions I'm (finally!) going to talk about.

part. Ideally, or what was I doing so far was just adding a predefined style from the [Overleaf Bib styles page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles) but it doesn't have the style I am required to have. The closest are the `ieee` and `chem-angew` styles. Can they be modified somehow?

What I'd like is

> [#] Initial letter of the name(s) followed by their 1 or 2 last names, "title of the paper", *magazine*, vol., no., (year) page-page

> [#] Initial letter of the name(s) followed by their 1 or 2 last names,  *name of the book*,  edition, publisher, (year).

And when citing the [#] appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start, a word of warning: If this style is for a submission of a paper to a journal or a publisher, `biblatex` might not be your best bet. Very often publishers have their own templates that come with a BibTeX style or at least with instructions how to generate the bibliography. Generally, publishers do not accept `biblatex` submissions. (See also [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864.))

---

Most `biblatex` style modifications can be made directly in the preamble of your document. Indeed, all modifications that can be made in `biblatex.cfg` can be made in the preamble and vice versa. Since `biblatex.cfg` is easily forgotten about, I usually recommend people just write their modifications to the document preamble.

It is possible to use `biblatex.cfg` also on Overleaf: Create a new blank file called `biblatex.cfg` by clicking on the "New File" icon on the top left. Then just add your `biblatex` modifications there. See for example https://www.overleaf.com/read/cbcnvhhbmdwx.

But as I mentioned above, I don't think this is necessarily the best way forward.

Here is a start for your style with the modifications directly in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-numeric,
  giveninits=true,
  articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcomma\space}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{date}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”, Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, 4 (1998) pp. 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

I used a `biblatex-ext` style to make some of the modifications even easier than in standard `biblatex`. You can find more details about this in the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed all your instructions except for the creation of the `biblatex.cfg` and worked almost correct except for the articles format, instead of using "...", uses <<...>>.  So I'm creating the `biblatex.cfg` file, but what do I do with the `bibliography.bib` where I have all my bibliography?

Comment: Nevermind, I figure it out. It has to do with the packages, I have different packages, and only added `\usepackage{csquotes}` to the packages I had. But I then commented that, and now displays "..." instead of <<...>>. What exactly was the `.cfg` file for? it worked with `.bib`

Comment: @veronika The `.cfg` file contains `biblatex` settings and definitions that modify your style. This code can also be written to the document preamble. The `.bib` file contains your bibliography entries. You can simply upload your file to Overleaf or create a new file with `.bib` file extension. `.cfg` and `.bib` have nothing to do with each other.