# biblatex bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I used to  build my bibliographies with BibTeX and a bibliography style file spbasic3.sty. It provided exactly the bibliography style necessary for Springer publications. Now, I had to switch to Biblatex to be able to put the references at the end of each chapter, but I can no longer use a bibliography style. I tried more than one biblatex style, at the end I found "nature" that is probably one of the closest to what I need; still it looks terrible for my use. Then I removed ISSN and DOI passing the options `isbn=false` and `doi=false`, finally I got rid of the  urk adding `\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{}` to the preamble. Still, I have only the first author listed ("Lastname, FirstInitial et al."), but I generally needs all of them or, sometimes three or six. Is there a way to achieve a fine tuning af the bibliography style according to the publisher instruction like using a style file? Where can I find a complete list of the axailable Biblatetex styles (as apa-style, chicago-style and so on)?

Comment: Note that if you are planning to submit to Springer, you will probably not be able to use `biblatex`. `biblatex` is completely incompatible with the usual BibTeX approach to bibliographies and so might break your publisher's workflow. Before you do anything else, get in contact with your editor and discuss your options with them. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864.

Comment: This time my work will not be submitted to Springer; however I was wandering how to do it in the future

Comment: One more thing: removing the url adding \renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{} to the preamble prevents me from using when I need it (for example citation of web pages. Is there a way to add the url only when I need it? Otherwise, I think I will have to edit the .bib file by hand.

Comment: How do you want to tell `biblatex` that you want to use the URL field for some works and not for others. If you do not redefine `url+urldate` and instead set the option `url=false,` at load-time, `biblatex` will drop all URLs except for `@online` entries. (If you need to know more, I think this should be a new question with an example document and an exact description of what you want and need.)

Comment: So it will show the url on the `@online` entries? That will suffice

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately even the @online entries lack of the url? any solution? Can I , at least, change preference per chapter or per section?

Comment: Ask a new question explaining what you want to do and what you are doing with an example document. As the example in https://gist.github.com/moewew/473d016f1213cacc91864613bc0fd7f7 shows a global `url=false,` suppresses URLs for all types except `@online`. (As I said before, do not redefine the `url+urldate` macro. I'm also assuming standard styles. If you use a specialised style, things might be different.)

Comment: thank you. Apparently the problem was the line `renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best list of 'easily available' styles is probably the `biblatex` topic page on CTAN https://ctan.org/topic/biblatex.

It isn't a simple list of all styles with style examples, though, and you'll have to click through to the separate bundles and styles to see what they look like.

Herbert Voß's "LaTeX Referenz" (in German, 4th ed. 2019, https://www.dante.de/dante-e-v/literatur/latex-referenz/) has a long list of `biblatex` style examples. I have the print version of that book, but I'm not sure if there is an ebook version.

---

If you are planning to write your own style, I would usually recommend to base it on one of the standard styles. Some of the more advanced contributed styles (`biblatex-apa`, `biblatex-chicago`) are very specialised, highly complex and were not written with customisability in mind.

There are great many ways to customise a `biblatex` style. Some of the first steps one might take are shown in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).