# What is the proper way to represent a talk at a conference (with no proceedings) in BibTeX (hopefully via Zotero)?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, zotero

I use [zotero](http://www.zotero.org) to manage my bibliography, and export collections to BibTeX when I'm writing in LaTeX. I use `apacite` as my style (I'm a psychology student).

I have a citation that should end up looking like this:

> Ranney, M., Cheng, F., Garcia de
>   Osuna, J., & Nelson, J. (2001,
>   November). Numerically Driven
>   Inferencing: A New Paradigm for
>   Examining Judgments, Decisions, and
>   Policies Involving Base Rates. Paper
>   presented at the annual meeting of the
>   Society for Judgment and Decision
>   Making, Orlando, FL.

It is a "paper" which is really a talk at a conference with no proceedings. The closest I can get is with a [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) "Presentation" with the following in the type field. Ends up as a "misc" in the BibTeX file:

using

```
@misc
...
type = {Paper presented at the annual meeting of the Society for Judgment & Decision Making}
...
```

Yields the following in my LaTeX / BibTeX output (unwanted square braces):

> Ranney, M., Cheng, F., Osuna, J. G.
>   de, & Nelson, J. (2001). Numerically
>   driven inferenc- ing: A new paradigm
>   for examining judgments, decisions,
>   and policies involving base rates
>   [Paper presented at the annual meeting
>   of the Society for Judgment & Decision
>   Making]. Orlando, FL.

Or, I can get close by hand-adding a `booktitle` field to the misc entry.

Note that Zotero outputs the "right thing" (to a word doc, or plain text, etc.) using a presentation, `type = Paper, conference = the annual meeting of the Society for Judgment & Decision Making`.

Anyway, I can just hand-code this as a lecture, but that sucks a little for my current work-flow.

Any ideas / hacks for how to deal with the problem much appreciated!

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/how-to-apa-6th-in-latex) doesn't quite speak to my question, but does imply that maybe I shouldn't be using apacite...

Comment: If anyone's interested, there's a sister thread in the zotero forums [here](http://forums.zotero.org/discussion/7648/citing-a-conference-presentation-from-a-symposium/#Item_6)

Comment: you may want to have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973) workflow using Zotero, `biblatex`, `biber`.

Comment: @doctorate Thanks for mentioning that! My current workflow is pretty similar to yours, I think (except mine is Vim based, and I'm using LuaLaTeX). Unfortunately, the way Zotero does bibtex export, I need to fix up approximately a third of the entries by hand anyway. So, the auto-matic approach doesn't save me too much time. I also just enable the more traditional bibtex key autocompletion. I've been thinking that the "right" solution would be to allow a generic search string that biber could interpret and run against the zotero DB. That is, we re-think what "keys" are altogether...

Comment: you welcome, Hmm, it seems that you do a lot of formatting tags to the web captured references in Zotero, but there should be no problem with that since you do it once and for all, it is part of the deal. But one thing might be relevant is the way Zotero auto-generate the citation keys using the title might bring some hassles see this [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114297/tweaking-of-biblatex-style-to-show-emphasized-species-name/115173#115173), some problems with tag parsing I have noticed, please let me know if you experience the same otherwise I should've remvd it

Comment: @DavClark I just had this same question... and here you are, asking it five years ago. <3

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have used

```
@unpublished{key,
title= {talk title},
author = {author names},
year = {year},
note= {conference name},
URL= {url link to talk abstract if any},
}
```

to cite conference talks in my thesis

Comment: Yeah - I think that does what I want too... for now, I've settled on using "misc," which I'm not certain is any different under the hood from unpublished. "misc" is no different in its output than the apacite-specific class "lecture," which seems to be the most semantically appropriate thing, but I'd rather not use apacite-specific classes! Instead of "note" I'm using "howpublished." But anyway, I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @DavClark Thanks for the comment. That was exactly what was needed. If you put it as answer and accept it, I will upvote it.

Comment: No worries - I think it's more straightforward to just leave the answer all together!

Comment: Somewhere in my LaTeX wanderings, I acquired the criterion for using `@unpublished`: Document having author & title but not formally published.  In my personally maintained text templates for the different BibTeX entries, I have author and title fields designated as optional under `@misc` but not as optional under `@unpublished`.  I conducted a time-limited search for the source of this guidance but haven't found it.

Answer (score 12):

Both @misc and @unpublished put the "Paper presented at" in parens, "[" and "(" respectively.

```
@booklet{key,
author = {author},
title = {title},
howpublished= {Paper presented at the meeting of Organization Name, Location},
year = {year}
}
```

This looks more like Example 7.04 of APA 6 Publication Manual (page 206)

Comment: How about a full qualified answer, with an example document?

Comment: Did you try misc with apacite?

Comment: `@booklet` works great if you don't want the parentheses added by `@misc`. Thank you! Here is my example (used with `apa6`) if anyone wants one: `@booklet{Girard2016b,
author = {Girard, Jeffrey M and Wright, Aidan G C and Stepp, Stephanie D and Pilkonis, Paul A},
howpublished = {Symposium conducted at the meeting of the Association for Psychological Science, Chicago, IL},
year = {2016, May},
title = {Interpersonal dynamics in
couples with personality pathology}
}`

Comment: this is all helpful, but for something like this wouldn't the exact date be appropriate? How would a person get biblatex-chicago to add the full date?

Answer (score 1):

For a conference session (e.g., talk or in my case, a poster) formatted in APA7, I was finally able to finagle the format with this. Note that the addendum is not automatically closed off with a period, so it's admittedly a bit hacky in that you have to explicitly add the period within the closing brace.

```latex
@unpublished{citekey,
    author       = {\textbf{Last1, F1.}, and Last2, First2 and Last3, First 3},
    title        = {My super cool poster presentation or conference session},
    date         = {2024-01-01/2024-01-03},
    howpublished = {Conference session},
    addendum     = {Conference Name, City, State, Country.}
}
```

The result should be:

**Last1, F1.**, Last2, F2., & Last3, F3. (2024, January 1–3). *My super cool poster presentation or conference session* [Conference session]. Conference Name, City, State, Country.