# Conference contributions as references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

For my PhD thesis I am obliged to cite all my contributions, not only papers but also posters and talks given at conferences. Now I am struggling how to do this best. My best try so far looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{Me2014,
author = {Me, P.},
title = {{Some Title}},
addendum = {Poster presented at some conference, Bremen, Germany}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Test citation~\cite{Me2014}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However, this produces the following:
[image]

This looks weird since I did not provide any booktitle which results in an empty `In`. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just change the type from `@inproceedings` to `@unpublished`, which is a pretty flexible type.

[image: Screenshot using @unpublished in place of @inproceedings]

Answer (score 6):

Possible duplicate of this question: [What is the proper way to represent a talk at a conference (with no proceedings) in BibTeX (hopefully via Zotero)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18194/what-is-the-proper-way-to-represent-a-talk-at-a-conference-with-no-proceedings)

Normally, conferences have *proceedings* which are published before the corresponding conference takes place and contain the written version of your poster (short paper) or talk (long paper). In such a case, you don't cite your talk or poster per se, you cite the paper published in the Proceedings. This is the case where you would want to use @inproceedings and where it should be done like so:

```
@inproceedings{tag,
author = {P. Me},
title= {Some Title},
booktitle   = {Proceedings of the n-th edition of some conference},
year= {some year},
publisher = {The publisher of the proceedings},
pages     = {page where your paper starts-ends},
url       = {official link to the online version}
}
```

For unpublished papers, you would use @unpublished and for posters or talks with no written paper attached to it and available somewhere on the internet, you would use @misc

Comment: In my field not all conferences have proceedings, and those that do typically publish the proceedings well after the conference (perhaps a year later).

Comment: Incidentally, `@misc` seems like the right entry-type, but, at least in the numeric-comp style, it creates an entry with an italicised title, which is inappropriate when referring to a talk or conference poster.