# How to enter conference papers in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

**UPDATE** *(September 2016)*:

The issue described below has been brought to the attention of the `biblatex-chicago` developer. He will be looking into making the package more compatible with the standard `biblatex`.  As of now it is not possible to use `biblatex` fields such as
`eventdate`,
`eventtitle`,
and 
`eventtitleaddon`, with `biblatex-chicago`.

---

I've had a hard time to figure out how to deal with papers presented at conferences, lectures, and the like.  Neither the biblatex nor the biblatex-chicago manuals are very helpful on this.

Chicago Manual of Style (and I believe others too) recommend including "sponsorship, location, and date of the meeting at which a speech was given or a paper presented," which should follow the title (see CMoS 14.226—14.227).  So they should look more or less like:

> Antelope, Antonia. "Some Title." Lecture, Unicorn University, New
>   York, April 1, 2008.
>
> Bear, Bruno. "Title of Talk." Paper presented at the Annual Meeting of
>   The Research Association, San Francisco, CA, May 15, 2015.

<s>The manual doesn't say anything about what happens to the date when the year moves to the front in the author-date system.</s>
**UPDATE:** I just got an email from the CMoS staff responding to this question saying "There is no need to repeat the year at the end." So it would be in author-date:

> Bear, Bruno. 2015. "Title of Talk." Paper presented at the Annual Meeting of The Research Association, San Francisco, CA, May 15.

Now I couldn't figure out how to create correct bibliography entries for these cases. Concerning the correct type, `@conference` is now a legacy alias for `@inproceedings`, the latter works well for papers that have been included in some proceedings, but not for unpublished ones.

And concerning the fields to use, `venue` seemed to be designed for the location, as in the biblatex manual it is described as the "location of a conference, symposium, …" but the field is completely ignored in `biblatex-chicago`. 
`biblatex` also includes 
`eventdate`,
`eventtitle`,
and 
`eventtitleaddon`,
but none of them is printed with the -chicago version.

So with:

```
@inproceedings{conferencetest,
    Author = {Antelope, Antonia},
    Eventdate = {2008-03-01},
    Eventtitle = {Lecture},
    Organization = {Unicorn University},
    Title = {Some Title},
    Venue = {New York},
    Year = {2008}}
```

I get only:

> Antelope, Antonia. 2008. “Some Title.” Unicorn University.

There are a few other related questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18194/what-is-the-proper-way-to-represent-a-talk-at-a-conference-with-no-proceedings)
and 
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256655/conference-contributions-as-references?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but they don't really provide satisfying solutions, either recommending using the @misc category, or @unpublished.

Of course, one can simply put everything in a `titleaddon` field, but since there are already dedicated fields for everything, it doesn't seem to me to be the ideal approach.

So is there any way how to get `venue`, `eventtitle`, `eventdate`, etc. to print in `biblatex-chicago`?  Or how else to handle them?

Comment: If the `biblatex-chicago` style does not implement a `@talk`-like entry type or a `@conference` type that is not really an `@inproceedings`, you will have to go with what is available (`@misc`, `@unpublished`, maybe even `@report` again ...), you can of course ask the maintainer nicely to implement this entry type if the CMS has specific directions on it (after all `biblatex-chicago` implements the `@music`, `@video`, `@audio`, `@artwork` entry types).

Comment: @moewe I have a draft of an email to David, with a few suggestions (also from the other posts), but wanted to make sure that I'm not missing anything and also gather all ideas first, to not have to write multiple emails. — I'm wondering though, is there a way to get standard `biblatex` functionality back into `biblatex-chicago`? Since the former does have all the necessary fields defined already...

Comment: As far as I know, `biblatex-chicago` is written from scratch and does not make use of any of the standard `biblatex` styles (except of course `biblatex.def`).

Comment: Did you get in touch with the developer? What should we do about this question? It feels more like a feature-request than a real question...

Comment: @moewe Yes I did, he was very thankful for the feedback (also about the other issue w/ `gentextcite`) and will be looking into adding more biblatex features. The problem was he started developing biblatex-chicago when many of the field referred to above did not exist yet. — You could either close the question, or I could add a note on top that this might be addressed in future releases of the package. (So others won't try this as it won't work.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it effectively amounts to a feature request to the `biblatex-chicago` author. The author is notified and will look into it.

Comment: @moewe that's fine with me

Comment: I got lucky to find this post, and I'd like to raise my hand in opposition to closing questions like this. I didn't know it amounted to a feature request, and I would have spun my wheels a ton if answers like, "It's not possible right now," didn't exist.