# Biblatex reference list entry for unpublished paper presented at symposium (APA)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I need to create a reference list entry according to APA standard for a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327368869_Word_Embedding_through_PCA) presented at a [conference](https://clasp.gu.se/news-events/the-second-swedish-symposium-on-deep-learning-) which does not have published proceedings.

The approrpiate format from the APA manual is likely this:

> Contributor, A. A., Contributor, B. B., Contributor, C. C., &
>   Contributor, D. 0.
>       (Year, Month). Title of contribution. In F. E. Chairperson (Chair), *Title of
>       symposium*. Symposium conducted at the meeting of Organization Name,
>       Location.

Example:

> Muellbauer, J. (2007, September). Housing, credit, and consumer
>   expenditure. In S. C. Ludvigson (Chair), *Housing and consumer behavior.*
>   Symposium  conducted at the meeting of the Federal Reserve Bank of
>   Kansas City, Jackson  Hole, WY

That however does not match the format chosen in this question: [What is the proper way to represent a talk at a conference (with no proceedings) in BibTeX (hopefully via Zotero)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18194/what-is-the-proper-way-to-represent-a-talk-at-a-conference-with-no-proceedings)

How do I create an entry of that format with Biblatex? The question I linked is about Bibtex and the answers there don't work for Biblatex.

My entry so far is

```
@conference{basirat_2018,
    title = {Word {Embedding} Through {PCA}},
    author = {Basirat, Ali},
    year = {2018},
    month = {September},
    venue = {Gothenburg, Sweden},
    eventtitle = {Swedish Symposium on Deep Learning},
    % chariman??
    % publisher = {Centre for Linguistic Theory and Studies in Probability} % wrong key I guess
}
```

producing

[image]

But there is no *Symposium conducted at the meeting of* in the compiled entry.

## edit

Ok, I improvised like this:

```
@conference{basirat_2018,
    title = {Word {Embedding} {Through} {PCA}},
    author = {Basirat, Ali},
    year = {2018},
    month = {September},
    note = {In \emph{Swedish symposium on deep learning}. Symposium conducted at the meeting of Centre for Linguistic Theory and Studies in Probability, Gothenburg, Sweden.}
}
```

Gives the right output. Only the `chair` part is missing, on which there is no information for this symposium.

[image]

Comment: There is—strictly seen—only one source for the details: the manual. I do not have it myself though. ☞ _Publication manual of the American Psychological Association_, 6th ed., 2nd printing [or later], 2010.

Comment: I am aware. But I don't have it and so far managed without it.

Comment: Ok, I got the ebook version now... eff. I looked it up and the format is different from what the website said.

Comment: That’s why I recommended the source, I’ve been there myself. One of these days I hope all manuals like this should be freely available on the web, in their full form.

Comment: If you found an acceptable solution, please don't include it in the question, write an answer instead.

Comment: I don't consider that a solution, but a workaround for when you don't have too many of these types of entries.

Answer (score 2):

The type `@conference` is automatically converted to `@inproceedings`. While `@inproceedings` is usually only used when there are published conference proceedings, you can get a sort of acceptable output even in this case.

The trick is to put the conference name in the `booktitle` field.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{basirat,
  title      = {Word Embedding Through {PCA}},
  author     = {Basirat, Ali},
  date       = {2018-09},
  venue      = {Gothenburg, Sweden},
  booktitle  = {Swedish Symposium on Deep Learning},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,basirat}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Basirat, A. (2018, September). Word embedding through PCA. In Swedish symposium on deep learning. Gothenburg, Sweden.]

---

You may want to debate whether or not to include the `2018` in the `booktitle`: `booktitle = {Swedish Symposium on Deep Learning 2018},` or whether to include the fact that this was the second such symposium `booktitle = {The Second Swedish Symposium on Deep Learning},`.

---

I didn't include the

> Symposium conducted at the meeting of Centre for Linguistic Theory and Studies in Probability, Gothenburg, Sweden.

bit, because that didn't sound right to me, but you could put it into `eventtitle` or `booktitleaddon`.

Note also that the [conference website](https://clasp.gu.se/news-events/the-second-swedish-symposium-on-deep-learning-) says

> Organised by Chalmers Area of Advance Information and Communication Technology, Chalmers Department of Computer Science and Engineering, and CLASP at University of Gothenburg.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't sound right to you? I agree it is weird, but it says so in the APA manual, as copy pasted into my question. Unless I am reading their "regular expression" wrong. Also, why are you hinting at the "Organised by..." part? Do you mean I need to include that in the reference somehow?

Comment: No, my reading is correct, there is also an example in the book that contains the *Symposium conducted at* bit.