# How do I use APA-style citations with BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to APA 6th in LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/how-to-apa-6th-in-latex)

I am just getting started with BibTeX for the first time, and wondering how do I can use APA format.  I assume there's more than one way to do this, so what are my options, and what do you recommend?  Not doing anything fancy, just a simple article.

Right now I just have this LaTeX document, "doc.tex":

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{cite}

    \begin{document}

    \title{Sample Document}
    \author{Bob Smith}
    \date{Today}
    \maketitle

    Blah blah blah blah blah blah by Bob ~\cite{BobsBook01}. 

    \bibliography{mybib}{}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \end{document}
```

And I have this bibliography file, "mybib.bib":

```
    @misc{ BobsBook01,
           author = "Bob Smith",
           title = "The Book of Bob",
           publisher = "Bob's Publishing",
           year = "2011"
    }
```

I'm compiling this into a pdf with pdflatex using this Makefile:

```
    doc.pdf : doc.tex doc.bbl
            latex doc
            pdflatex doc
    doc.bbl : doc.tex doc.aux mybib.bib
            bibtex doc
    doc.aux : doc.tex
            latex doc
```

The output of the bibliography looks like this:

```
    [1] Bob Smith. The book of bob, 2011.
```

But I need it in APA format, which I think should be something like this:

```
    [1] Smith, B. (2011). The book of bob. Bob's Publishing.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/how-to-apa-6th-in-latex, which covers APA style more generally?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the package apacite.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
```

...

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}
```

See:
[apacite package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/) and
[apa document class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa)

Comment: Awesome, my system already had apacite on it, too.

Comment: but with it the \printbibliography won't work right?

Comment: apacite doesn't seem to work with `sagej` documentclass

Comment: test_sect.tex (line 6)
Undefined control sequence. (^^I\item 1: \cite{test123} ...)